# How can I generate this "domain coloring" plot?

Tags: plotting, complex

I found this plot on Wikipedia:

[image: domain-colored plot of sine function]

> [Domain coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) of $\sin(z)$ over $(-\pi,\pi)$ on $x$ and $y$ axes. Brightness indicates absolute magnitude, saturation represents imaginary and real magnitude.

Despite following the link and reading the page nothing I have tried is giving me the result shown.  How should this be done?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @Ajasja that's fair, but I ask you to cut me some slack: I've posted 395 answers to this site so I'm not unwilling to exert myself.  In this case I was having a mental block so nothing I tried was worth sharing.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @belisarius lol :-) (I'm assuming that's your quirky humor again.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard :D. That is a nice picture, BTW. I wonder why the circle's centres have those black lumps.

Comment: It's is noteworthy that Claudio Rocchini provided C/C++ code for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Color_complex_plot.jpg on that same page

Comment: I'm very late to the party - but thought I should link in [this similar old stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5385103/421225).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Building on Heike's `ColorFunction`, I came up with this:

[image]

The white bits are the trickiest - you need to make sure the brightness is high where the saturation is low, otherwise the black lines appear on top of the white ones.

The code is below. The functions defined are:

- `complexGrid[max,n]` simply generates an $n\times n$ grid of complex
  numbers ranging from $-max$ to $+max$ in both axes.
- `complexHSB[Z]` takes an array $Z$ of complex numbers and returns an
  array of $\{h,s,b\}$ values. I've tweaked the colour functions
  slightly. The initial $\{h,s,b\}$ values are calculated using Heike's
  formulas, except I don't square $s$. The brightness is then adjusted
  so that it is high when the saturation is low. The formula is almost
  the same as $b2=\max (1-s,b)$ but written in a way that makes it
  `Listable`.
- `domainImage[func,max,n]` calls the previous two functions to create
  an image. `func` is the function to be plotted. The image is
  generated at twice the desired size and then resized back down to
  provide a degree of antialiasing.
- `domainPlot[func,max,n]` is the end user function which embeds the
  image in a graphics frame.

---

```
complexGrid = Compile[{{max, _Real}, {n, _Integer}}, Block[{r},
    r = Range[-max, max, 2 max/(n - 1)];
    Outer[Plus, -I r, r]]];

complexHSB = Compile[{{Z, _Complex, 2}}, Block[{h, s, b, b2},
    h = Arg[Z]/(2 Pi);
    s = Abs[Sin[2 Pi Abs[Z]]];
    b = Sqrt[Sqrt[Abs[Sin[2 Pi Im[Z]] Sin[2 Pi Re[Z]]]]];
    b2 = 0.5 ((1 - s) + b + Sqrt[(1 - s - b)^2 + 0.01]);
    Transpose[{h, Sqrt[s], b2}, {3, 1, 2}]]];

domainImage[func_, max_, n_] := ImageResize[ColorConvert[
    Image[complexHSB@func@complexGrid[max, 2 n], ColorSpace -> "HSB"],
    "RGB"], n, Resampling -> "Gaussian"];

domainPlot[func_: Identity, max_: Pi, n_: 500] :=
  Graphics[{}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> max, RotateLabel -> False, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Re[z]", "Im[z]", 
      "Domain Colouring of " <> ToString@StandardForm@func@"z"},
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calibri", 12},
   Prolog -> Inset[domainImage[func, max, n], {0, 0}, {Center, Center}, 2` max]];

domainPlot[Sin, Pi]
```

Other examples follow:

It's informative to plot the untransformed complex plane to understand what the colours indicate:

```
domainPlot[]
```

[image]

A simple example:

```
domainPlot[Sqrt]
```

[image]

Plotting a pure function:

```
domainPlot[(# + 2 I)/(# - 1) &]
```

[image]

I think this one is very pretty:

```
domainPlot[Log]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the accept. It's still not quite right - I have a feeling the original might have gone through more sophisicated processing than just computing HSB values from function samples.

Comment: You're welcome.  Re: processing, quite possibly, however I wasn't looking for an exact replication.  Yours is a complete answer as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Lovely images! Trying to imagine where to use these for a proper `Texture[]`.

Comment: +1, brilliant! In addition to just being lovely images, I love how the poles and branch cuts are clearly visible.

Comment: Incidentally, I posted this on Facebook. The response I got: "Holy crap, mathematica keeps getting more and more awesome."

Comment: Really nice work on the update.  I'm sure this will earn a "Good Answer" badge soon.

Comment: Simon, I'm having some trouble using `domainPlot`: I keep getting `Coordinate 6.283185307179586 should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.`  Since I'm seeing `2 Pi` this looks like it's coming from `Inset`; has the syntax for `Inset` changed in version 8?

Comment: Strange, it *works* if I use `domainPlot[Log, N@Pi, 500]` but *fails* if I use `domainPlot[Log, Pi, 500]` ; I'm not seeing why that should be.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the documentation says that `Inset` was last modified in version 7, so perhaps there was a bug that was fixed. Can you confirm that using `N[2 max]` for the last argument of `Inset` remedies the problem in version 7?

Comment: Simon, yes, using that, or as I prefer ``2` max`` fixes it for version 7.  Also for version 7 the option `Resampling->"Gaussian"` cannot be used but it looks fine without it.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've updated the code to work in version 7.

Comment: @rcollyer, that's great! Your friend has excellent taste. My friends would just think I was weird if I posted domain colouring plots on Facebook :-)

Comment: The update is terrific!

Comment: I am wondering how could you work out such wonderful picture^-^

Comment: I would upvote this twice, if I could, just for its beauty.

Comment: On Mathematica V.9, the `complexGrid[]` function was wrong for me, the `Outer[]` was not giving the expected result (it puts z with Re[z]<0 and Im[z]<0 in the upper left quadrant). See e.g. the following code: `Outer[Plus, I {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}] // MatrixForm` I replaced it with `Outer[Plus, r, I r // Reverse]\[Transpose]` which works for me.

Comment: @guerom00, well spotted, thanks! A simpler correction is `Outer[Plus, -I r, r]`

Comment: @SimonWoods by any chance, do you know what transform turns a unit circle into the real number line?

Comment: @rcollyer, I'm not sure what you mean. There must be many ways to map from the complex unit circle to the real number line, e.g. `Re[z]/(1-Im[z])` but I don't get how it relates to this answer?

Comment: @SimonWoods it doesn't have any relationship to the answer. I was grasping at straws for another problem, and I thought such a transformation might help. (Further investigation suggests not.) So, remembering this answer, I thought you might know. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Simon, I notice that presently the color orientation of the first graphic no longer matches that of the output of `domainPlot[Sin]` -- do you think this is something that should be corrected?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I'll update it. The original contained two errors and I only fixed one.

Answer (score 36):

Not as pretty as the one in the original post, but it's getting in the right direction I think:

```
RegionPlot[True,
 {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[Rescale[Arg[Sin[#1 + I #2]], {-Pi, Pi}],
     Sin[2 Pi Abs[Sin[#1 + I #2]]]^2,
     Abs@(Sin[Pi Re[Sin[#1 + I #2]]] Sin[Pi Im[Sin[#1 + I #2]]])^(1/
        4), 1] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems that the hue of the colour function is a function of `Arg[Sin[z]]`, saturation is a function of `Abs[Sin[z]]` and the brightness is related to `Re[Sin[z]]` and `Im[Sin[z]]`.

Comment: +1 Very close. What did you wanted to say about the brightness?

Comment: ...and if you use the color scheme in Thaller's package along with Heike's idea, you get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q0IfA.png), whose coloring is a wee bit closer to the one in the OP.

Answer (score 24):

This is a good way :

```
DensityPlot[ Rescale[ Arg[Sin[-x - I y]], {-Pi, Pi}], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
             MeshFunctions -> Function @@@ {{{x, y, z}, Re[Sin[x + I y]]}, 
                                            {{x, y, z}, Im[Sin[x + I y]]},
                                            {{x, y, z}, Abs[Sin[x + I y]]}}, 
             MeshStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.8], Thickness[0.001]], 
                           Directive[Opacity[0.7], Thickness[0.001]], 
                           Directive[White, Opacity[0.3], Thickness[0.006]]}, 
             ColorFunction -> Hue, Mesh -> 50, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Another ways to tackle the problem, which apprears promising.

```
ContourPlot[ Evaluate @ {Table[Re @ Sin[x + I y] == 1/2 k, {k, -25, 25}], 
                         Table[Im @ Sin[x + I y] == 1/2 k, {k, -25, 25}]}, 
             {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

and

```
RegionPlot[ Evaluate @ {Table[1/2 (k + 1) > Re @ Sin[x + I y] > 1/2 k, {k, -25, 25}],
                        Table[1/2 (k + 1) > Im @ Sin[x + I y] > 1/2 k, {k, -25, 25}]},
            {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
            ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[Re@Sin[x + I y]]]]
```

[image]

These plots seem to be good points for further playing around to get better solutions.

Answer (score 23):

I already mentioned Bernd Thaller's package `` Graphics`ComplexPlot` `` in the comments; if one blends the ideas from Artes's and Heike's answers, and then use the function `$ComplexToColorMap[]` from Thaller's package (I won't include it here; again, see the package for that), we get this:

[image: domain-colored plot]

```
Needs["Graphics`ComplexPlot`"] (* Thaller's package; get it yourself *)

f1 = RegionPlot[True, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> ($ComplexToColorMap[Abs[Sin[#1 + I #2]], 
     Arg[Sin[#1 + I #2]], {Pi, 1/10, 1, 1/10, 1}] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 200];

f2 = ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@{Table[Re@Sin[x + I y] == 1/2 k, {k, -25, 25}], 
   Table[Im@Sin[x + I y] == 1/2 k, {k, -25, 25}]}, {x, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100, ContourStyle -> Gray];

f3 = ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[Abs@Sin[x + I y] == 1/2 k, {k, -25, 25}], {x, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100, ContourStyle -> White, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5];

Show[f1, f2, f3]
```

The `$ComplexToColorMap[]` function could probably be optimized a fair bit for new *Mathematica*, but I won't get into that for now. One might also consider tweaking the `Opacity[]` of the contour lines for the absolute value as well, but I'll leave that as an experiment for the reader.

---

Another thing you can try:

```
RegionPlot[True, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> ($ComplexToColorMap[Abs[Sin[#1 + I #2]], 
     Arg[Sin[#1 + I #2]], {Pi, 1/50, 1, 1/50, 1}] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> 51, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Re[Sin[#1 + I #2]] &, Im[Sin[#1 + I #2]] &}, 
 MeshStyle -> Gray, PlotPoints -> 95]
```

Answer (score 17):

With Mathematica 12.0, there's now a [`ComplexPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot.html) function that replaces user made solutions. As with other `Plot` functions, it allows us to specify a [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) option to manipulate how to color the plot. This particular coloring is implemented natively in the `"CyclicReImLogAbs"` option.

So the modern equivalent is

```
ComplexPlot[Sin[z], {z, -Pi - Pi I, Pi + Pi I}, 
 ColorFunction -> "CyclicReImLogAbs", Frame -> False]
```

[image: Plot Result]

Comment: complements user made solutions*