# How can this type of optical illusion be created in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, code-request, generative-art

I see these around the web and would like to make them in *Mathematica*.
Combining them in an array is actually quite mesmerizing!

[image: Moving Illusion]

Comment: is it my eyes or do I see it spinning? This only happens when I am not looking at it directly. I bet that either `The Mathematica Guidebook: Graphics` or `Graphica: The World Of Mathematica Graphics` both by Graphics  Michael Trott will have something like this !

Comment: @Nasser You would think so, but I did check my copy and nothing like this is posted.  Weird spinning effect is due to something called simultaneous contrast.  Very cool!

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24148/how-can-this-image-optical-illusion-be-created-with-mathematica

Comment: @MichaelE2 Notice I left out the pink floyd logo? ;) Actually not related other than title.  Very different problem and solution.

Comment: Is this image supposed to look as if it were spinning? Doesn't work for me. Must be because of vision impairment.

Comment: As usual: what have you tried? What *Mathematica* related difficulty are you having in producing this image?

Comment: @Jens Just a question like the one Michael E2 mentions above.  Tried researching it like I mentioned above and also checked demonstrations projects.  Why -2 on the question but +4 on the answer? Seems odd and unfair.  Please go to chat if you have more questions.

Comment: I didn't downvote and instead upvoted now... since apparently someone had fun wit this after all. But I also agree with @MichaelE2.

Comment: RHall, I too agree with @Michael. Please see [this meta discussion](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/887/5) for why you got a -3 on the question. This question clearly falls in point 1 and 2 of nikie's answer...

Comment: @rm-rf added my comments to that thanks for the link.

Comment: You might be interested in this [blog](http://intothecontinuum.tumblr.com/tagged/logpolar-coordinates) which also animates such optical illusions.

Comment: [background information](http://www.michaelbach.de/ot/mot_rotsnake/index.html) for this illusion

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Forward Mapping**

One way to do it is to create the texture for one tile and then transform repeated copies of it in a way that resembles the original illusion.

First we create the tile:

```
tile = Module[{KeyHole},
    KeyHole[base_] := Sequence[
      Disk[{0, 1/3} + base, 1/10], Rectangle[{-1/30, 1/15} + base, {1/30, 1/3} + base]
    ];
    Image@Rasterize@Graphics[
      {Orange, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}],
       Blue,   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}], Rectangle[{1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1}],
       Black, KeyHole[{0,   0}], KeyHole[{1/2, 1/2}], KeyHole[{1,   0}],
       White, KeyHole[{0, 1/2}], KeyHole[{1/2,   0}], KeyHole[{1, 1/2}]
      },
      PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}
    ]
  ]
```

[image: tile texture]

Then we make repeated copies of it:

```
floortex = ImagePad[
    ImageRotate[#, Right],
    5 First@ImageDimensions[#], "Periodic"
  ] &[tile]
```

[image: floor texture]

For the transformation we can use an exponential mapping, which will turn the $y$-coordinate into an angle and the $x$-coordinate into an exponent for radial distance. Since the mapping is most elegantly described with complex numbers but we need to work with cartesian coordinates we can use `ComplexExpand` to do the work for us (which is not very hard in this case, but could be useful for trying out other mappings):

```
ComplexExpand[Through[{Re, Im}[ Exp[x + I y] ]]]
(* {E^x Cos[y], E^x Sin[y]} *)
```

Since this is so useful we wrap it in a procedure for easy reuse:

```
CartesianMappingFromComplexFunction[f_] := Function[{x, y}, 
    Evaluate@ComplexExpand@Through[{Re, Im}[f[x + I y]]]
  ]
```

Now we just need a way to transform our checkerboard image according to our mapping, which is exactly what `ImageForwardTransformation` does:

```
ImageForwardTransformation[
  floortex,
  {Exp[#[[1]]] Cos[#[[2]]], Exp[#[[1]]] Sin[#[[2]]]} &,
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
  DataRange -> {{-2 \[Pi], 0}, {0, 2 \[Pi]}},
  Background -> White
]
```

[image: finished optical illusion]

**Inverse Mapping**

Michael E2 pointed out another possible way, namely using the inverse mapping, so let's try that! Up to now we basically let Mathematica do a forward transform of our checkerboard into the disk shape and let it fill the holes via interpolation and throw away the points that got mapped outside of our `PlotRange` which is kind of wasteful.

Instead we can go the reverse route and start with the destination pixel locations and ask where they came from before undergoing that exponential mapping. Since we made the effort to generalize the procedure of getting a cartesian mapping from any complex function we now can just plug in the inverse complex function, which is the (or rather a branch of) the complex `Log`, and get

```
CartesianMappingFromComplexFunction[Log]
(* Function[{x, y}, {Log[x^2 + y^2]/2, Arg[x + I*y]}] *)
```

Great! Now we can use `ImageTransformation` with our inverse mapping

```
ImageTransformation[
  floortex,
  {Log[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2]/2, Arg[#[[1]] + I*#[[2]]]} &, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  DataRange -> {{-2 \[Pi], 0}, {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}}, Padding -> White
]
```

where we had to adjust the `DataRange` in order to coincide with the target set of `Arg`. Because we evenly sample the target image instead of the original checkerboard, we get much better image quality with less computation (14s vs. 19s on my machine).

To see the difference here are images from both approaches, but generated from a tile with `RasterSize -> 128` and `ImageResolution -> 128` given as options to `Rasterize`:

[image: coarse illusion from forward transform approach]

`ImageForwardTransformation`

[image: coarse illusion from inverse transform approach]

`ImageTransformation`

With `ImageTransformation`, we basically get antialiasing for free, which can be further customized via the `Resampling` option.

Comment: Very cool solution thanks!  How does ComplexExpand function apply to this? I don't see it used.

Comment: @RHall He used `ComplexExpand` to simply justify to the formula he is using inside the `ImageForwardTransformation`.

Comment: @PlatoManiac Thanks very much!

Comment: @RHall This is very similar to the method of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24148/how-can-this-image-optical-illusion-be-created-with-mathematica/24649#24649) to the question I said above was related, which uses a log-polar transformation to convert a regular pattern in the plane to circular pattern.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Seems like it would be and I did review your solution, but it crashes MMA 9 on my Mac, and I can not test it or modify it. This one worked, and I can modify it without crashing.  Thanks.

Comment: @RHall  Thies' `floortex` is rather large and perhaps that's why [Sum it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/874)'s solution crashes.  I'm not sure why.  `ImageTransformation` (Sum it's)  and `ImageForwardTransformation` (Thies') are basically inverse operations.  I would think that if one works, so would the other.  Both work in V9/Mac/16GB for me.

Comment: @Thies Sorry for the chatter on your answer - I should have said, nice answer, as usual.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Actually i liked that you pointed out the related question, had forgotten about that one and it was nice to compare with the inverse approach, so more chatter please :D

Comment: @Thies @RHall Ok, then one more thing I would add is that the `ImageTransformation` method runs 9X faster on my machine, 6 vs. 54-55 sec. Code: `LogPolar[{x_, y_}] := { Log[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ArcTan[x, y]}; 
ImageTransformation[floortex, LogPolar, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  DataRange -> {{-2 π, 0}, {-π, π}}, 
  Padding -> White]`.  Cheers! :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for trying that out and some code to test right away! Gave me the motivation to add another section to show both approaches.

Comment: Cool!  Too bad I can't upvote again.

Answer (score 15):

I decided to take a slightly different approach. Instead of transforming an image, I thought of constructing a function that will look like the illusory figure in the OP after performing the log-polar transform. Here's what I came up with:

```
checkerboard[x_, y_] := Boole[EvenQ[Floor[x] - Floor[y]]]
keyholes[x_, y_] := Boole[(Mod[x - 1/2, 1] - 1/2)^2 + (Mod[y, 1] - 2/3)^2 < 1/25 ||
                          (13/30 < Mod[x - 1/2, 1] < 17/30 && 1/8 < Mod[y, 1] < 1/2)]

DensityPlot[With[{u = 32 ArcTan[x, y]/π, v = 4 Log[x^2 + y^2]},
                 (1 - keyholes[u, v]) (2 checkerboard[u, v] - 1) +
                 keyholes[u, v] (2 checkerboard[u - 1/2, v] - 1)/3],
            {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
            ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Orange, Black, White, Blue}, #] &), 
            Exclusions -> None, Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 405,
            RegionFunction -> (#1^2 + #2^2 < 1 &)]
```

[image: dizzy keyholes]

---

Here is a `ContourPlot[]` version of a slightly less "busy-looking", but still sufficiently eye-popping illusion:

```
ContourPlot[With[{u = 12 ArcTan[x, y]/π, v = 2 Log[x^2 + y^2]},
                 (1 - keyholes[u, v]) (2 checkerboard[u, v] - 1) +
                 keyholes[u, v] (2 checkerboard[u - 1/2, v] - 1)/3],
            {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
            ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Orange, Black, White, Blue}, #] &), 
            ContourStyle -> None, Exclusions -> None, Frame -> False, 
            PlotPoints -> 405, RegionFunction -> (#1^2 + #2^2 < 1 &)]
```

[image: ooh, twisty...]

Answer (score 4):

The illusion can be created completely in vector form without using any plotting function. I'll start from the wonderfully elegant [solution by Thies Heidecke](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30483/280).

The key change is that instead of `Circle` and `Rectangle` I use `Polygon`-based approximations for them:

```
Clear[squarePoints, KeyHole, tile]
squarePoints[{xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}, n_: 6] := 
  Join[Array[{#, ymin} &, n, {xmin, xmax}], Array[{#, ymax} &, n, {xmax, xmin}]];
KeyHole[base_] := 
  Sequence[Polygon[CirclePoints[{0, 1/3} + base, 1/10, 24]], 
   Polygon[base + # & /@ {{-1/30, 1/15}, {1/30, 1/15}, {1/30, 1/3}, {-1/30, 1/3}}]];
tile[base_] := {
   Orange, Polygon[{squarePoints[{0, 1/2} + base, {1/2, 1} + base], 
     squarePoints[{1/2, 0} + base, {1, 1/2} + base]}], 
   Blue, Polygon[{squarePoints[{0, 0} + base, {1/2, 1/2} + base], 
     squarePoints[{1/2, 1/2} + base, {1, 1} + base]}], 
   Black, KeyHole[{0, 0} + base], KeyHole[{1/2, 1/2} + base], KeyHole[{1, 0} + base], 
   White, KeyHole[{0, 1/2} + base], KeyHole[{1/2, 0} + base], KeyHole[{1, 1/2} + base]};
```

Now the illusion can be generated as follows:

```
nCircle = 10; levels = 10;
gr = Graphics[N@Table[tile[{x, y}], {x, nCircle}, {y, levels}], 
   ImageSize -> 600] /. {y_Real, x_Real} :> {E^(2 Pi x/nCircle) Cos[2 Pi y/nCircle], 
    E^(2 Pi x/nCircle) Sin[2 Pi y/nCircle]}
```

> [image: graphics]

We can turn on antialiasing using `Style`:

```
Style[%, Antialiasing -> True]
```

> [image: graphics]

Comment: Related Wolfram Community thread: "[Remove strange line in animation](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/601091?p_p_auth=L3zdl1ga)" (see especially the first post by Sander Huisman).