# Circularly multiplying a bitmap image

Tags: image-processing, complex

I would like to do the following:

1) Take an image inside a circle and a radius of the circle, and imagine that there are 2 copies of the radius like the handles of a Japanese fan fully opened to 360 degrees.

2) Squeeze the image by the factor `n`, sort of like closing the above Japanese fan from 360 to 360/`n` degrees. The image now occupies `1/n`th of the circle.

3) Copy/paste the squeezed image `n` times inside the circle so that the combined image would occupy the entire circle again with `n` circularly squeezed copies of itself.

An alternative description of the same (just corrected "disk" to "punctured disk", etc):

I'd like to project an image on the unit disk in $z\in\mathbb{C}, |z|\leq 1$ onto the part the Riemann surface of $z^{1/n}$ above the unit disk, with all the points on the branches above $z$ receiving the same pixel as on $z$. Then I would like to "unwind" the punctured Riemann surface (less zero) onto the punctured unit disk (less zero) and exporting the resulting image.

The map from the punctured disk  to *each* branch of the Riemann surface: $z=(|z|,\arg z)\to (|z|, (\arg z)/n)$. The map from the Riemann surface to the disk: $u=(|u|, \arg u)\to (|u|,n\arg u)$.

How do I do that in `Mathematica`?

Comment: Some legwork of your own to do: are you aware of any (hopefully conformal) maps from a disk to a sector?

Comment: @J.M.: I'm interested in a very specific map, from (open disk - radius) to (open sector): $(|z|,\arg z)\to (|z|,(\arg z)/n)$, which is not conformal.

Comment: Alright... have you seen `ImageTransformation[]` and `ImageForwardTransformation[]`? But even before that: test your purported mapping with `ParametricPlot[]` to be certain that it does what you think it does.

Comment: Possibly [related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30479/how-can-this-type-of-optical-illusion-be-created-in-mathematica/30483#30483)