# How to apply a conformal map to a jpg (or other image)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, image-processing, complex

I would like to apply a conformal map to a jpg. For example, the map $z\mapsto z^2$ to this image:

http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/d/l225/m/mGyeriV7l-YArkeBd9oMUng.jpg

Any help on how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can this image (optical illusion) be created with Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24148) (esp. Sum it's answer)

Comment: `ImageTransformation[
 Import["http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/d/l225/m/mGyeriV7l-\
YArkeBd9oMUng.jpg"], #^2 &, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]`

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/blog/QuadraticCamera.html

Comment: Thanks -- both of these comments help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ImageTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageTransformation.html).  Check the documentation for many examples.