# How to obtain an animated prism using Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, animation, generative-art

Is it possible to create a GIF animation like the one shown below, using *Mathematica*?

[image: prism]

---

**UPDATE**

I have mainly two puzzles:

1. How do I obtain the rendered trigonometric curves (unnecessarily animated);- So I want to know what kind of *Mathematica* commands can create a "3D rendered tube" like curves per the parametric equations? -- I mean curves that look like the ones in the picture below:

[image: tube1][image: tube2]

2. How do I make sure these curves are **smoothly** continuous even after being refracted; I also need some clues in representing the equations of the curves  (in parametric form or other forms), before and after being refracted; In order to handle the refraction smoothly and continuously, I think parametric equation forms of the curves are necessary since some of the curves may have only implicit form.

For example:

[image: wave]

This photo was found from the Internet; I need such clues to create similar GIF animations using *Mathematica*;

Before creating similar GIF animations, I need to solve the two puzzles; I think there is no other obstacle for me to create it;

**Update$^{(2)}$**

I am not simply requesting code, answers resolve the two questions mentioned and illustrated with photos above will be accepted. I hope this can be made clearer.

However, there is no reason that I refuse answers with codes which can create similar GIF photos.

Now there is already acceptable answer. I will try to work on it.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Which of Mathematica plotting commands cause you trouble?

Comment: Are these curves by 3D plots or other command? I just have no idea of it. Do you have an answer to it? I am eager to learn it

Comment: I will update my question.

Comment: have you tried *something*, or did you just find a picture and want someone to write code for you to recreate it?  There is no dark side in the moon, really. Matter of fact, it's all dark.

Comment: thank you! I further updated it

Comment: So you want to do 2D or a 3D graphics? the animated graphic is 2D but you're asking for 3D tubes!?

Comment: Yes, 2D curves; with 3D rendering effects. All the sine / cosine curves are basically planar curves (2D) with rendering/lighting effects (3D). Did I make it clearer?

Comment: Usually we discourage "GimmeTehCodez" questions. See [the meta post here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/489/245). There are [exceptions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24148/245) but they should be rare.

Comment: This question can probably be separated into multiple questions, making it more reasonable for you to provide a starting point (i.e. some code) for others to build on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of a function drawn along a parametric path:

```
 points = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1.8, 1.8}, {2, 2}, {3, 3/2}, {4, 1}};
 path = BSplineFunction[points];
 ipath = Interpolation[
      Transpose@({Prepend[Accumulate[Norm /@ Differences@#], 0], #} &@
          Table[path@x, {x, 0, 1, .01}])];
 plen = ipath[[1, 1, 2]];
 d2 = Derivative[1]@ipath;
 Show[{ParametricPlot[path@x, {x, 0, 1}], 
       ParametricPlot[ipath@x - (1 + (x/plen)^2) Sin[40 x + 10 x^2] 
          {1, -1} Normalize[Reverse@d2@x]/10, {x, 0, plen}], 
       ListPlot[points, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Dashed]}, 
       PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Note the trick here is to get the parametric representation in terms of the path length.

3D version:

```
Show[Graphics3D@
      Tube@Table[
         Append[ipath@x - (1 + (x/plen)^2) Sin[
            20 x + 5 x^2] {1, -1} Normalize[Reverse@d2@x]/10 , 0],
             {x, 0, plen, .01}], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this

```
Animate[
 Graphics[{
   Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {120, 100}],
   EdgeForm[{Thick, GrayLevel[0.6]}], GrayLevel[0.3], 
   Triangle[{{110, 10}, {10, 10}, {60, 90}}],
   EdgeForm[None], GrayLevel[0.8], 
   Polygon[{{0, 30}, {0, 35}, {35, 50}, {31, 43}}], Inset[
    Plot[.0025 t Sin[c .25 t], {t, 0, 100}, Axes -> False, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-1.5, 1.5}}]
    , {64, 45}]
   }]
 , {c, 12, 8}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this is very useful. Let's neglect the refraction index difference when using Snell's law. Only from KnotData related commands I saw 3D tube like curve redenring, e.g.: `Graphics3D[{Orange, Specularity[White, 70], 
  KnotData[{8, 3}, "ImageData"]}, Boxed -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0.1, 5}]`

Comment: @LCFactorization check the edit. Is it the rendering effect for the sin curves you asking for?

Comment: I have posted 3D curve examples to illustrate my request; additionally, did you notice how the original GIF `sin` curves handle `refractions`? this is another question of mine. When the curve intersects the edge of medium, the transmission direction changes but the curves are kept as smoothly continuous.

Comment: In order to handle the refraction smoothly and continuously, I think parametric equation form of the curves is necessary since some of them might have only implicit form.

Answer (score 3):

I'll leave the animation to somebody else:

```
refWave[{x1_, y1_}, {m1_, m2_}, h_, d_, f_, x_] := {x, 
   y1 + (x - x1) (m1 + (m2 - m1) With[{t = Clip[Rescale[x - x1, {-h, h}], {0, 1}]}, 
                                      t^2 (3 - 2 t)])} + 
   d Sin[2 π f x] Normalize[{-Piecewise[{{m1, x - x1 < -h}, {m2, h < x - x1}},
                                        (m1 + m2)/2 + (m2 - m1) (x - x1)
                                                      (3/2 - ((x - x1)/h)^2)/h], 1}]

ParametricPlot[Table[refWave[With[{u = 1/2 + t/10}, {-Sqrt[3]/2 (u - 1), (3 u - 1)/2}],
                             {1/10 + t/20, 1/3 - 3 t/2}, 1/20, 1/50, 8/(5/4 - t), x],
                     {t, 7/10, 1/10, -1/10}] // Evaluate, {x, -1/2, 3/2},
               AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> None, Background -> Black, 
               Epilog -> {White, Polygon[{{-17/(20 Sqrt[3]), 3/20},
                                          {-6 Sqrt[3]/25, 7/25},
                                          {-3/2, (12 Sqrt[3] - 5)/250},
                                          {-3/2, (17 Sqrt[3] - 45)/300}}]}, 
               PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 3/2}, {-3/4, 5/4}}, 
               PlotStyle -> (RGBColor /@ {"#9400D3", "#4B0082", "#0000FF",
                                          "#00FF00", "#FFFF00", "#FF7F00", "#FF0000"}), 
               Prolog -> {Directive[FaceForm[GrayLevel[1/10]],
                                    EdgeForm[Directive[Gray, Thick]]], RegularPolygon[3]}]
```

[image: prism]