# How do I draw a Circular Graph colored like this in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I must plot some data in radians and would like to use this image as a background to that graph. Although it looks good, the lines are degraded in image form; thus, the reason for this question.  Can something like this be drawn in *Mathematica*?  [image: Colored Circular Graph]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a start. I'll leave the labeling and fine tuning the details to you:

```
With[{thin = {Thin, Opacity[0.4]}},
    RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
        ColorFunction -> (Hue[ArcTan[#, #2]/(2 π)] &), 
        ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, Frame -> False,
        Mesh -> {21, 21, 10, 7, 47}, MeshStyle -> {thin, thin, thin, thin, thin}, 
        MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, Norm[{#1, #2}] &, ArcTan[# , #2] &, ArcTan[# , #2] &}
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: Just noticed the hues are rotated slightly, how can that be corrected? Thanks very much!

Comment: @RHall `Hue` has `Red` at zero, whereas your image has red at $\pi/6$. So all you need to do would be to change the numerator inside `Hue[...]` to `ArcTan[#, #2] - π/6`.

Answer (score 14):

It is of course possible to draw everything manually.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 With[{
   colArea = 
    Polygon[#2, VertexColors -> ConstantArray[Hue[#1/(2 Pi)], 3]] & @@@ 
    Table[{phi, {{0, 0}, {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {Cos[phi + 2 Pi/colors], 
       Sin[phi + 2 Pi/colors]}}}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi - 2 Pi/colors, 2 Pi/colors}],
   gridLines = 
    Table[{{x, -#}, {x, #}} &[Sqrt[1 - x^2]], {x, -1, 1, 
      2/(grid - 1)}],
   radLines = Table[{{0, 0}, {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}}, 
      {phi, 0, 2 Pi - 2 Pi/radiants, 2 Pi/radiants}],
   cirLines = With[{
     circle = Table[{Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}]},
     Table[r*circle, {r, 0, 1, 1/circles}]
   ]},
   Graphics[{
    colArea, Black, Thin, Line[gridLines], 
    Line[Map[Reverse, gridLines, {2}]], Darker@Gray, Line@radLines, 
    Line /@ cirLines}]],
 {circles, 3, 10, 1},
 {radiants, 4, 20, 1},
 {grid, 5, 20, 1},
 {{colors, 20}, 4, 120, 1}
 ]
```

### Update

By the way, it is not required to create a new coordinate list for all graphics primitives. This was only done to make the code verbose enough. The color disk, the radial lines and the circles can all be created easily using the same underlying data. Here the `Span` operator (`;;`) becomes handy, to achieve high resolution in the color disk, but have only some radial grid lines.

```
With[{pts = Append[#, First[#]] &@ Table[{r {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, phi/(2 Pi)}, 
  {phi, 0, 2 Pi, .1}, {r, 0, 1, .1}]},
Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, First[#1], First[#2]}, 
  VertexColors -> (Hue /@ {{0, 0, 1}, Last[#1], Last[#2]})] & @@@ 
    Partition[pts[[All, -1, {1, 2}]], 2, 1],
  Black, Opacity[.5], Line[pts[[;; ;; 3, All, 1]]], Line[Transpose[pts[[All, All, 1]]]],
  Opacity[.2], {Line[#], Line[Map[Reverse, #, {2}]]} &@
    Table[{{x, #}, {x, -#}} &@Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1, .1}]
  }]]
```

[image]

Comment: Since I'm usually the one suggesting drawing from Graphics primitives I must vote for this. :-)

Comment: @halirutan +1 Very Nicely done! I too am curious what the colors slider will do.  Is that hue angle? Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The colorslider wasn't so spectacular as I excpected, so I removed it ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Then here per request the original color-slider-included version.

Answer (score 14):

Just for fun, only the color wheel drawing part done with `Disk` sectors:

```
With[{sectors = 360},
 angle = 2 Pi/sectors;
 Graphics[
  Table[{Hue[i/sectors], EdgeForm[{Thick, Hue[i/sectors]}],  
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {i angle, (i + 1) angle}]}, {i, 0, sectors - 1}]]]
```

I had to use a thick `EdgeForm` because without it I was getting a moiré pattern in the rendering.

[image: color wheel]

Comment: Nice wheel, but the yellow must be at vertical.  Thanks!

Comment: Just add a fixed offset to the angle calculation: `With[{offset = Pi/6, sectors = 360}, angle = 2 Pi/sectors;
 Graphics[
  Table[{Hue[i/sectors], EdgeForm[{Thick, Hue[i/sectors]}], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {i angle + offset, (i + 1) angle + offset}]}, {i, 
    0, sectors - 1}]]]`

Comment: Performance can be improved and the code simplified by turning off anti-aliasing and omitting `EdgeForm`: `With[{sectors = 360}, angle = 2 Pi/sectors;
 Graphics[Table[{Antialiasing -> False, Hue[i/sectors - 1/12], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {i angle, (i + 1) angle}]}, {i, 0, sectors - 1}]]]` -- note also that the very center of the graphic is cleaner this way.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Removing the moiré pattern,`With[{sectors = 360},
 With[{offset = 0, angle = 2 Pi/sectors}, 
  Graphics[Table[{Hue[i/sectors], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, 
      1, {i angle + offset, (i + 1.8) angle + offset}]}, {i, 0, 
     sectors - 1}]]]]`

Answer (score 13):

I set out to do this differently from R.M, but I ended up with something very similar.  Nevertheless, I think there is a certain simplicity that results from my using `ParametricPlot`, so here it is:

```
ParametricPlot[
 r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1},
 Axes -> False, Frame -> False,
 Mesh -> {47, 11, {0}, 8, 27, 27},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &, #3 &, #4 &, # &, #2 &},
 MeshStyle -> ({#, #2, #2, #, #, #} &[Opacity[0.5], Thick]),
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3 - 1/12] &)
]
```

[image: color wheel with a mesh]

A complication that arose with this method is that I needed to specifically add the line at zero (that is, east), as I could not get `Mesh` to do this automatically.

Comment: @MrWizard  +1 for a cool solution! The hue angle is off a bit from the example though.  `Hue[#3 - (2 Pi/5.8)]` will fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: @R Hall, better to use `Hue[#3 - 1/12]`, as rm suggested in his answer. That way, red exactly corresponds to $\pi/6$.

Comment: @J.M. yes of course you are correct. thanks!

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, I forgot what I was subtracting from and confused myself.  Corrected.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another method based on `RegionPlot[]`, similar to rm's solution. There are a few wrinkles in this version, however:

1. I use `PolarPlot[]` to generate the ticks for me. (I know about the hidden functions behind the generation of the polar ticks, but I couldn't figure how to use them directly.)
2. I use the saturation and brightness arguments of `Hue[]` to generate the meshes as part of the color function. The idea was <strike>stolen</strike> adapted from the solutions of Heike and Simon in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7359), but I did change a few things around.

Now, on to the routine:

```
hueWithMesh[x_, y_, hx_: 1/10, hr_: 1/8, ht_: 1/24, r1_: 2/5, r2_: 1/2, g_: 1/5] := 
  Block[{ph = Arg[x + I y]/π, s, b}, 
        s = r1 + (1 - r1) Abs[(Mod[2 Abs[x + I y]/hr, 2, 1] - 2) (Mod[ph/ht, 2, 1] - 2)]^g;
        b = r2 + (1 - r2) Abs[(Mod[2 x/hx, 2, 1] - 2) (Mod[2 y/hx, 2, 1] - 2)]^g;
        Hue[ph/2 - 1/12, s, Max[1 - s^2, b]]]

 Show[PolarPlot[1/Sqrt[2], {t, -π, π}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 6,
                PlotRange -> 1, PlotStyle -> None, PolarAxes -> Automatic], 
      RegionPlot[Abs[x + I y] <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
                 ColorFunction -> (hueWithMesh[#1, #2] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
                 Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 200], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: a gridded color wheel]

As you might notice from the implementation of `hueWithMesh[]`, the parameters `hr`, `ht`, and `hx` all control the spacing in the rectangular and polar meshes, while `r1`, `r2`, and `g` all control the saturation/brightness for the meshes. You can tweak these parameters to your taste.

Comment: +1 for extreme cool factor! I will have to go to school on this code.   Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thanks! This solution sure was fun to write. :)

Comment: Simon's answer is the first thing I thought about as well, when I saw the question, but I couldn't get the highlights working in time and couldn't be arsed to dig deeper :)

Comment: @rm, at this juncture, I should confess that I had to stare at Simon's routines for a full hour before figuring how to take it apart for this question.

Comment: Ok, I'm relieved then... If you had to spend an hour on it, I'm very certain that taking the lazy route was the best course of action for me =)

Answer (score 7):

Since you've already gotten a bunch of fine answers, I'll just quietly post this variation:

```
DensityPlot[ArcTan[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
            ColorFunction -> (Hue[# - 7/12] &), Frame -> False, Mesh -> {30, 30, 8, 49}, 
            MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, Abs[#1 + I #2] &, Arg[#1 + I #2] &}, 
            MeshStyle -> {Opacity[1/3, GrayLevel[1/5]], Opacity[1/3, GrayLevel[1/5]],
                          Opacity[1/3, GrayLevel[1/2]], Opacity[1/3, GrayLevel[1/2]]},
            PlotPoints -> 45, RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#1, #2}] < 1 &)]
```

[image: color wheel]

Tick addition is left for as an exercise for less lazy readers.

Comment: +1 for fractionalization.  Very Elegant Solution! Thanks!

Comment: (I've got another variation in the works, but I'll post it much later.)

Answer (score 2):

Using `Polygon`:

```
With[{d = 2 Pi/360}, 
 Graphics[Table[{Hue[t/( 2 Pi)], EdgeForm@Hue[t/( 2 Pi)], 
    Polygon@{{0, 0}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {Cos[t + d], Sin[t + d]}}}, {t, d, 2 Pi, d}]]
 ]
```