# Plotting rainbow circle

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to plot a parametric circle in rainbow colors. It should go round once, but I'd like to be able to make it go round the rainbow an arbitrary amount of times.

I currently have:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u] Sin[Theta], Cos[u] Sin[Theta], 
  Cos[Theta]} /. Theta -> Pi/6, {u, -Pi, Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.01]], 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][(Arg[x + I y] + Pi)/(2 Pi)]]]
```

Which I think should choose a color from the `ColorData` named `Rainbow` (which changes only between 0 and 1 (the result of `Arg` lies between `-Pi` and `Pi`, so adding `Pi` and dividing the resulting interval by `2 Pi` will give me a number between 0 and 1) depending on the angle of the circle. I get an almost decent result if I divide by `Pi/2` instead of `2 Pi`:
[image: Nearly rainbow circle]

But I have no idea why there is yellow and green twice. I'm certainly missing something, does anyone know what?

Comment: Look up `ColorFunctionScaling`.

Comment: @J. M. Adding `ColorFunctionScaling->False` "fixes" it. But why would it being set to True mess up my own scaled values?

Comment: If you look at the docs, you'll see that with the setting `ColorFunctionScaling -> True`, the `x` and `y` are scaled even before being fed to your color function; that's different from scaling `Arg[]`, the output.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25871/5478

Answer (score 3):

Since you're providing the scaling, you don't want *Mathematica* to do it, so

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u] Sin[Theta], Cos[u] Sin[Theta], Cos[Theta]} /. Theta -> Pi/6, 
   {u, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.1]], 
   ColorFunction -> 
     Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][(Arg[x + I y] + Pi)/(2 Pi)]],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building on m_goldberg's answer, you can also use `Hue` instead of `Rainbow` -- this provides brighter colors and is still pretty much around the rainbow.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u] Sin[Theta], Cos[u] Sin[Theta], 
             Cos[Theta]} /. Theta -> Pi/6, {u, -Pi, Pi}, 
         PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.1]], 
         ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[(Arg[x + I y] + Pi)/(2 Pi)]], 
         ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]