# How to draw a polygon with hue color like this one (Koch snowflake)?

Tags: graphics, color, filling, fractals

I know how to construct the Koch snowflake:

```
f[{a:{x1_,y1_},b:{x2_,y2_}}] :=
  Partition[{a,(2a+b)/3,{3(x1+x2)+√3(y1-y2),√3(x2-x1)+3 (y1+y2)}/6,(a+2b)/3,b},2,1];
pts=Join@@Nest[Join@@f/@#&,.5{{{0,0},{2,0}},{{2,0},{1,-√3}},{{1,-√3},{0,0}}},5];
Graphics[Polygon @ pts]
```

and draw a hue disk ([How do I draw a Circular Graph colored like this in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25871)), but how do I draw a Koch snowflake with hue-based coloring like [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/lindenmayer-systems/)?
Vector diagrams are better than images.

[image: color wheel on Koch snowflake]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a hue disk as you [suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25880/427) (but slightly tweaked to get the colours in the right spot):

```
hueDisk = With[{sectors = 360}, angle = 2 Pi/sectors;
  Table[{Hue[1 - i/sectors], EdgeForm[{Thick, Hue[1 - i/sectors]}], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 0.6, {\[Pi]/2 + i angle, \[Pi]/2 + (i + 1) angle}]}, {i, 0, sectors - 1}]];
```

Then we can use the [FilledCurve technique](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3728/427) to draw the snowflake over the top:

```
Graphics[{hueDisk,
  FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black],
  FilledCurve[{
    {Line[{ImageScaled[{-2, -2}], ImageScaled[{2, -2}], 
       ImageScaled[{2, 2}], ImageScaled[{-2, 2}]}]},
    {Line@With[{m = Mean@pts}, # - m & /@ pts]}}]}]
```

[image: hueflake]

Answer (score 7):

One way is to use your code for the snowflake, and turn it into an image. Then use the code for the colored circle and turn it into an image. Then multiply:

```
f[{a : {x1_, y1_}, b : {x2_, y2_}}] := 
  Partition[{a, (2 a + b)/3, {3 (x1 + x2) + \[Sqrt]3 (y1 - y2), \[Sqrt]3 (x2 - x1) + 
       3 (y1 + y2)}/6, (a + 2 b)/3, b}, 2, 1];
pts = Join @@ Nest[Join @@ f /@ # &, .5 
     {{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}, {{2, 0}, {1, -\[Sqrt]3}}, {{1, -\[Sqrt]3}, {0, 0}}}, 5];
flake = ColorNegate[Image[Graphics[Polygon@pts], ImageSize -> 400]];
circle = Image[With[{sectors = 360}, angle = 2 Pi/sectors;
    Graphics[Table[{Hue[i/sectors], EdgeForm[{Thick, Hue[i/sectors]}], 
       Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {i angle, (i + 1) angle}]}, {i, 0,  sectors - 1}]]], ImageSize -> 400];
ColorNegate[ImageMultiply[flake, circle]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["`*"]
f[{a_,b_}]:={3a,2a+b,3/2(a+b)+√3/2(b-a).RotationMatrix[-Pi/2],a+2b,3b}/3;
pts=Nest[Join@@f/@Partition[#,2,1]&,.5{{0,0},{2,0},{1,-√3},{0,0}},3];
img=Colorize[Image@Rescale@Table[ArcTan[x,y+1.*^-6],{x,-200,200},{y,-200,200}],ColorFunction->Hue];
ImageAdd[img,Graphics[Polygon@pts]]

pts = # - Mean@pts & /@ pts;
Graphics[{Texture@img,Polygon[pts,VertexTextureCoordinates->Rescale@pts]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the Koch snowflake generator from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108202), and the current ability of *Mathematica* to plot over polygons, here is one more possibility:

```
kochinsert[pts_?MatrixQ] :=
           Insert[#, Composition[TranslationTransform[#[[2]] - #[[1]]], 
                                 RotationTransform[-π/3, #[[1]]]][#[[2]]], 3] &[
                     Transpose[{1 - #, #}] &[Subdivide[3]].pts]

koch[pts_?MatrixQ] := 
     Apply[Join, Prepend[Rest /@ Rest[#], First[#]]] &[kochinsert /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]]

ks = Polygon[Nest[koch, Append[#, First[#]] & @ N[CirclePoints[3]], 4]];
DensityPlot[ArcTan[-y, -x], {x, y} ∈ ks, BoundaryStyle -> Black, ColorFunction -> Hue,
            Exclusions -> None, Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 95]
```

[image: color wheel on Koch snowflake]

Answer (score 2):

**Using:**

- `KochCurve`: (introduced Mar 16, 2017)
- `ConicGradientFilling` (introduced Dec 16, 2020)

---

```
Clear["Global`*"];
cols = (Hue /@ Subdivide[1, 13]) // ColorConvert[#, RGBColor] & // 
    Reverse // RotateRight[#, 4] &;

reg = TransformedRegion[KochCurve[4]
     , #] & /@ {RotationTransform[Pi, {1/2, 0}]
    , RotationTransform[-Pi/3, {1, 0}]
    , RotationTransform[Pi/3, {0, 0}]};

ks = reg /. Line -> Sequence // Flatten[#, 2] & // DeleteDuplicates //
    CanonicalizePolygon@*Polygon;

Graphics[{ConicGradientFilling[cols], ks}]
```

[image]