# Prevent Plus from threading

Tags: functions, evaluation, symbolic

This is probably a very simple question, but I couldn't find a duplicate.

As everybody knows, `{x, y} + v` gives `{x + v, y + v}`. But if I intend `v` to represent a vector, for example if I am going to substitute `v -> {vx, vy}` in the future, then the result `{x + v, y + v}` is meaningless.

How I can indicate to Mathematica that `v` is not a scalar and functions like `Plus` should not treat it as one? I tried setting `$Assumptions = v ∈ Vectors[2]` but that didn't help.

Comment: I suppose you don't want to `Inactivate` `Plus` because there are other computations you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, everyone! I guess I should have been more forthcoming about my ultimate goal, namely getting a correct `PiecewiseExpand[f[t, 0, 2]]` for my [Koch snowflake parametrization](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102720/484), because I couldn't figure out make the answers here work for it. But seeing all the different approaches inspired a solution of my own that did work out (though still not as elegant as I would like).

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Inactivate`

```
pl = Inactivate[{x, y} + v, Plus]
```

[image]

As an indication to not being "active" the plus sign is dimmed

You can still use a (partially) inactivated expression

```
ti = pl * 8
```

[image]

and `Activate` it whenever you want

```
Activate[ti]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One workaround would be `ClearAttributes[Plus,Listable]` (The `Plus` is threading because of the `Listable` attribute). If you need the `Listable` attribute in another part of your code, you would need to run `SetAttributes[Plus,Listable]` to put the attribute back in.

```
ClearAttributes[Plus,Listable];
{x, y} + v

(* v + {x, y} *)
```

Or, you could simply use `Defer` (a bit tricky to use):

```
Defer[{x, y} + v]

(* {x, y} + v *)
```

Alternatively, you could use `Hold` (or `HoldForm`) and `ReleaseHold`:

```
ReleaseHold[Hold[{x, y} + v] /. v -> {vx, vy}]

(* {vx + x, vy + y} *)
```

Comment: Clearing `Listable` makes `{a,b}+{c,d}` not evaluate as expected.

Answer (score 5):

I like to wrap lists in some suitable function to block this evaluation. `MatrixForm` is good because it looks pretty, but an undefined function would also work.

```
a = MatrixForm[{x, y}] + MatrixForm[v]
```

Then, once you have concrete definitions for your arrays, take away the `MatrixForm`:

```
b = a /. v -> {1, 2}
b /. MatrixForm -> Identity
(* {1 + x, 2 + y} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use `Indexed` to represent `v` as its components in the calculation.

```
{x, y} + (Indexed[v, #] & /@ Range[2])
(* {x + Indexed[v, {1}], y + Indexed[v, {2}]} *)
```

Later when `v` is assigned the `Indexed` components will become `Part` values of `v`.

```
v = {1, 2};
{x, y} + (Indexed[v, #] & /@ Range[2])
(* {1 + x, 2 + y} *)
```

As a function

```
f[t_] := {x, y} + (Indexed[t, #] & /@ Range[2])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If there's a specific addition operation one wants to block, one can just apply a custom function instead, for example

```
{x, y} ~plus~ v
(* plus[{x, y}, v] *)
```

and replace it with `Plus` when one is ready:

```
{x, y} ~plus~ v /. v -> {vx, vy} /. plus -> Plus
(* {vx + x, vy + y} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, which doesn't require activation/replacement-by-identity/manual-indexing/etc. is to create a custom Plus function, which only evaluates for lists:

```
vectorPlus[a_?ListQ,b_?ListQ]=a+b;
```

With it you have:

```
vectorPlus[x, {q,r,s}]
vectorPlus[{q,r,s}, y]
vectorPlus[{q,r,s}, y] /. y->{a,b,c}
vectorPlus[{q,r,s}, {x,y,z}]
```

> vectorPlus[x, {q, r, s}]
>
> vectorPlus[{q, r, s}, y]
>
> {a + q, b + r, c + s}
>
> {q + x, r + y, s + z}