# Coordinates of the centers of the triangles composing a Koch snowflake

Tags: fractals

How do I obtain the coordinates of the centers of triangles composing the Koch snowflake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please search the site properly for existing answers before asking a new question. Following the answer by @Mark McClure [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/revolution-of-koch-snowflake) , getting the centers of the Koch snowflake triangles is a very easy job.

Centers at level `n=2`

```
(Mean /@ triangles[2])
```

Visualize them. Thx to the answer I linked above.

[image]

```
Graphics[{Table[{Darker[LightYellow, 1 - 1/1.2^(k - 1)], 
    EdgeForm[{Thin, Directive[Opacity@.3, Gray]}], 
    Polygon[triangles[k]], Darker[Red, 1 - 1/2^(k - 1)], 
    Point /@ (Mean /@ triangles[k])}, {k, 1, level}], {Orange, 
   Line[edges]}}]
```