# How can I make a surface of revolution from the given "TimeSeries"?

Tags: graphics, sound, time-series

I read [this article](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/02/12/spellbound-valentines-diy-art-from-3d-printed-sound/) and I tried to make a simple analog

```
tako = Import[
"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\tako\\kk\\My recording #2.wav"];


maxx = AudioBlockMap[Max, tako, {0.055, 0.001, HammingWindow}]
```

[image]

```
Show[AudioPlot[tako, AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotRange -> All], 
ListLinePlot[maxx, PlotStyle -> Red], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

then I tried

```
RevolutionPlot3D[InterpolatingPolynomial[maxx["Path"], x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

but it doesn't work.

does there exist a simple way to make `RevolutionPlot3D[]` from the `TimeSeries`?

(see "tako" audio file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kk4vovvjcpngm4k/My%20recording%20%232.wav?dl=0))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `InterpolatingPolynomial`, which results in an interpolation by a polynomial of order `Length[max["Path"]]-1=2824`. What you probably want instead if a piecewise interpolation, which can be done as follows:

```
if = Interpolation[maxx["Path"], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
RevolutionPlot3D[if[x], Evaluate@{x, Sequence @@ First@if["Domain"]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also decide to rotate around the `X` axis with option `RevolutionAxis -> "X"`:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[if[x], Evaluate@{x, Sequence @@ First@if["Domain"]}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, RevolutionAxis -> "X", MaxRecursion -> 4,PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

The approach I used in [this previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108202) can also be used here; that is, one can directly construct a `BSplineSurface[]` corresponding to the desired surface of revolution, without needing to use `RevolutionPlot3D[]`:

```
tako = Import["My recording #2.wav"];
maxx = AudioBlockMap[Max, tako, {0.055, 0.001, HammingWindow}];
path = maxx["Path"];

circPoints = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}};
circKnots = {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1};
circWts = {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1};

Graphics3D[BSplineSurface[Map[Function[pt, Append[#2 pt, #1]], circPoints] & @@@ path, 
                          SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> {1, 2}, 
                          SplineKnots -> {Automatic, circKnots}, 
                          SplineWeights -> ConstantArray[circWts, Length[path]]], 
           Boxed -> False]
```

[image: surface of revolution]