# Export high resolution 3D graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, export, fractals

There is a code for a [revolution of Koch Snowflake](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108202/30288) I just want to export it as an obj file (or any other 3D format)

```
kochinsert[pts_?MatrixQ] := 
Insert[#, 
Composition[TranslationTransform[#[[2]] - #[[1]]], 
  RotationTransform[-\[Pi]/3, #[[1]]]][#[[2]]], 3] &[
Transpose[{1 - #, #}] &[Subdivide[3]].pts]

koch[pts_?MatrixQ] := 
Apply[Join, Prepend[Rest /@ Rest[#], First[#]]] &[
kochinsert /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]]

halfkoch = {{0, 1}, {-1/(2 Sqrt[3]), 1/2}, {-Sqrt[3]/2, 
1/2}, {-Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {-1/Sqrt[3], 
0}, {-Sqrt[3]/2, -1/2}, {-1/(2 Sqrt[3]), -1/2}, {0, -1}};

snowflake = Nest[koch, N[halfkoch, 20], 4];

circPoints = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1,0}};
circKnots = {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1};
circWts = {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1};

graphics = 
Graphics3D[BSplineSurface[
Map[Function[pt, Append[#1 pt, #2]], circPoints] & @@@ snowflake, 
SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> {1, 2}, 
SplineKnots -> {Automatic, circKnots}, 
SplineWeights -> ConstantArray[circWts, Length[snowflake]]],Boxed -> False]
```

I simply tried to export it as an obj file, but the given file is a very low resolution.

```
Export["KochSnowflakeRe.obj", graphics]
```

before

[image]

after

[image]

Comment: I think maybe other format doesn't support NURBS surfaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use the code in [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/revolution-of-koch-snowflake/102749#102749) and convert the result to a `MeshRegion` using `DiscretizeGraphics`, then the result exports to OBJ at a reasonable resolution. Here's what it looks like on [3dviewer.net](https://3dviewer.net/):

[image]

You can also see an rotatable and colored version (after conversion to X3D) [in this Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@mcmcclur/x3d-upload). I added the color by manually editing the X3D file.

A couple of comments:

- Mathematica's export to external 3D formats is generally a bit weak. It makes a bit of sense, though, that we should be able to export `MeshRegion`s a bit easier, since the object is triangulated
- While [the answer you referred to](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108202/30288) looks nice in Mathematica, I'm not surprised it doesn't export well. Splines are meant to approximate smooth objects so it doesn't make much sense to represent a *fractal* object using splines.
- In principle, you should be able to generate a rotatable version of *any* `Graphics3D` object using `CloudDeploy`. That doesn't seem to work too well for these complicated graphics but, again, it works OK for the triangulated MeshRegion version.

Comment: Mark, I can’t seem to access the cloud deploy you’ve linked to.