# DensityPlot of periodic function

Tags: plotting

I can plot the phase of a complex function with `Arg`, using `Hue` as the `ColorFunction`:

```
DensityPlot[Arg[x + I y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
    ColorFunction -> Function[z, Hue[z/(2 Pi)]],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> All]
```

But this produces

[image: Output of DensityPlot]

with a white line where the phase jumps by 2π. Is there any way to get rid of this line and to avoid the unnecessary extra sampling near the discontinuity?

Comment: `Exclusions -> None`

Comment: See also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25871/5478