# plot and sum colors of the common region in hyper-graph?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, color

For the two complex weighted hypergraphs {$G_{1}: w1$ for edge $(d_{1},d_{2})$;  $G_{1}: w2$ for edge ($d_{1},d_{3}$) } sharing one vertex $d_{1}$, I use different color for the complex angle and transparency for the complex radial (usually a color wheel can stand for such complex domain, see [halirutan's solution for plotting colorwheel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25871/how-do-i-draw-a-circular-graph-colored-like-this-in-mathematica)).

Here the `HypergraphPlot` function is from [Jaebum Jung's hypergraph plotting](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HypergraphPlot):

```
fig1 = HypergraphPlot[{{Subscript[d, 1], Subscript[d, 2]}, {Subscript[d, 1], Subscript[d, 3]}}, 
  "SubsetBoundaryStyle" -> (Directive[EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.003], Black}], #] & /@ {Green, Red}), 
  "SubsetBoundaryScale" -> {2, 2, 2, 2}, "SubsetEdge" -> False, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

There in the above example {$G_{1}: w_{1}=1$, red color ; $G_{2}: w_{2}=I$, green color }, the hypergraph is plotting as following ***fig1***:

[image: fig1]

Now the question is how can I show the overlap region with the correct color for the summed weights $w_{3}=w_{1}+w_{2}$ for vertex $d_{1}$? Assume *red + green~ yellow*, **so the fig1 should be fig2** as I want. But I don't know how to show up the overlapped region.

[image: common fig]

The way I do is quite stupid -- adding one more hypergraph that only contains vertex $d_{1}$ with the correct color to cover the common region.

```
fig2=HypergraphPlot[{{Subscript[d, 1], Subscript[d, 2]}, {Subscript[d, 1], Subscript[d, 3]}, {Subscript[d, 1], Subscript[d, 1]}}, 
 "SubsetBoundaryStyle" -> (Directive[EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.003], Black}], #] & /@ {Red, Green, Yellow}), "SubsetBoundaryScale" -> {2, 2, 2, 2}, 
 "SubsetEdge" -> False, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

But I think it's not a good idea because if I have complicated hypergraphs and the common regions are randomly, I cannot always put additional edges to cover and I can see the adding edges cannot follow obviously the original overlapped curves.

Is there any clever way to do such color common regions with graphs? Thank you very much in advance! If something is unclear, thank you for pointing out!

Comment: What is `HypergraphPlot`? Is it the one [from function repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HypergraphPlot)?

Comment: @Silvia, Hypergraph is more general, which can contain arbitrary vertex in one edge.  yes, I use the function from Jaebum Jung's FunctionRepository for hypergraph. ha, sorry, I just found the link is wrong, I edited it now.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. `HypergraphPlot` is not a built-in function, so I was just asking for sure. I think the [tag:mathematical-optimization] tag is irrelevant here thus removed it. Please feel free to roll back if you believe otherwise.

Comment: @Silvia, thank you very much for pointing out :) I didn't realize that.

Comment: One way is to add `Opacity[.3]` into your `Directive` expression.

Comment: @ChipHurst, thank you for the infos, but i think it's a bit tricky and not the way I want. Because later I will use transparency for the strength of the color  (100% transparency: 0 -- white, 0% transparency: the real color, from 0 to 100%, adding transparency in the edge. ) , then it's not good to use `Opacity` to describe the common region. Sorry for unclear, I edited now.