# Dynamically getting the complex number in a color wheel via moving mouse?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, dynamic, complex

I have a color wheel domain which is used to describe complex numbers. I want to know is it possible to add a black spot which can be moved by mouse dynamically and return the complex number values of the spot's position?

Is it possible to do this by `Manipulate` or something similar? I'm not so familiar with the dynamically coding and I know how to make color wheel from the [halirutan and others' answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25871/how-do-i-draw-a-circular-graph-colored-like-this-in-mathematica).

[image: fig1]

Does anyone know this? Is it like adding a black bottom in the color wheel and then obtain the values when move the spot by mouse?

I appreciate all the comments and suggestions from you! Thank you very much!

> --------------------additional question -----------------------------------
>
> one additional thing: how to return the spot's complex values to a certain variables? I show the following example:

I have the following code, that I can adjust the angle `phi1` and radial `R1` which stands for a complex value and then automatically change the color.

```
RectangleC1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 3}];

Manipulate[
 With[
  {RegionC1 = R1 (Cos[phi1] + I*Sin[phi1])},

  Region1S = Abs[RegionC1]^2/4;
  If[Re[RegionC1] == 0 && Im[RegionC1] == 0, Region1Phi = 0,
   If[N[ArcTan[Re[RegionC1], Im[RegionC1]]] <= 0, 
     Region1Phi = N[ArcTan[Re[RegionC1], Im[RegionC1]]]/(2 Pi) + 1, 
     Region1Phi = N[ArcTan[Re[RegionC1], Im[RegionC1]]]/(2 Pi)];
   ];

  Icolorstyle = {Hue[Region1Phi, 1, 1, Region1S]};
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.001], Gray}], {Icolorstyle[[1]], 
     RectangleC1}}]
  ],
 {phi1, 0, 2 Pi}, {R1, 0, 1}
 ]
```

[image: fig2]

So what I do is:

```
RectangleC1 = Rectangle[{2, -2}, {5, 3}];
With[
 {pts = Append[#, First[#]] &@
    Table[{r {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, phi/(2 Pi)}, {phi, 0, 
      2 Pi, .1}, {r, 0, 1, .1}]},
 DynamicModule[
  {pt = {.5, .5}},
  Region1S = pt[[1]]^2 + pt[[2]]^2;
  If[pt[[1]] == 0 && pt[[2]] == 0, Region1Phi = 0,
   If[N[ArcTan[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]]] <= 0, 
     Region1Phi = N[ArcTan[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]]]/(2 Pi) + 1, 
     Region1Phi = N[ArcTan[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]]]/(2 Pi)];
   ];
  Icolorstyle = {Hue[Region1Phi, 1, 1, Region1S]};
  Graphics[
   {Polygon[{{0, 0}, First[#1], First[#2]}, 
       VertexColors -> (Hue /@ {{0, 0, 1}, Last[#1], Last[#2]})] & @@@
      Partition[pts[[All, -1, {1, 2}]], 2, 1], 
    Locator[Dynamic[pt, (pt = If[Norm[#] < 1, #, Normalize[#]]) &], 
     Style["\[FilledCircle]", FontSize -> 10]], Icolorstyle[[1]], 
    RectangleC1}, PlotLabel -> Dynamic[Style[pt, 16]]]
  ]
 ]
```

the result is:
[image: fig3]

It doesn't automatically change the color when I move the black spot
in the color wheel. Which part is missing?  Thank you so much for all
your help!

> figure out one solution:

```
RectangleC1 = Rectangle[{3, -2}, {6, 2}];
With[{pts = 
   Append[#, First[#]] &@
    Table[{r {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, phi/(2 Pi)}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi, .1}, {r, 0, 2, .1}]},
 DynamicModule[{pt = {.5, .5}},
  {
   Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, First[#1], First[#2]}, 
        VertexColors -> (Hue /@ {{0, 0, 1}, Last[#1], Last[#2]})] & @@@
       Partition[pts[[All, -1, {1, 2}]], 2, 1], 
     Locator[Dynamic[pt, (pt = If[Norm[#] < 2, #, Normalize[#]]) &], 
      Style["1\[FilledCircle]", FontSize -> 8]]}, 
    PlotLabel -> Dynamic[Style[pt, 12]]],

   Dynamic[
    Region1S = (pt[[1]]^2 + pt[[2]]^2);
    If[pt[[1]] == 0 && pt[[2]] == 0, Region1Phi = 0, 
     If[N[ArcTan[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]]] <= 0, 
       Region1Phi = N[ArcTan[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]]]/(2 Pi) + 1, 
       Region1Phi = N[ArcTan[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]]]/(2 Pi)];
     ];
    Icolorstyle = {Hue[Region1Phi, 1, 1, Region1S]};
    Graphics[{Icolorstyle[[1]], RectangleC1}]
    ]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a [`Locator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locator.html) to  [this answer by halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25877/125):

```
With[{pts = Append[#, First[#]] & @ Table[{r {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, phi/(2 Pi)}, 
    {phi, 0, 2 Pi, .1}, {r, 0, 1, .1}]}, 
 DynamicModule[{pt = {.5, .5}}, 
  Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, First[#1], First[#2]}, 
       VertexColors -> (Hue /@ {{0, 0, 1}, Last[#1], Last[#2]})] & @@@
      Partition[pts[[All, -1, {1, 2}]], 2, 1],
   Locator[Dynamic[pt, (pt = If[Norm[#] < 1, #, Normalize[#]]) &], 
     Style["●", FontSize -> 16]]}, PlotLabel -> Dynamic[Style[pt, 16]]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need `PointSize[Large], Black,` before `Locator[...]`

Comment: @kglr, this is very nice! Thank you very much for your help. Do you know how to add more spots if possible?

Comment: Thank you @m_goldberg. Removed it.

Comment: @XuemeiGu, you can do something like `DynamicModule[{pt1 = {.5, .5}, pt2 = {-.5, -.5}}, 
  Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, First[#1], First[#2]}, 
       VertexColors -> (Hue /@ {{0, 0, 1}, Last[#1], Last[#2]})] & @@@
      Partition[pts[[All, -1, {1, 2}]], 2, 1], 
    Locator[Dynamic[pt1, (pt1 = If[Norm[#] < 1, #, Normalize[#]]) &], 
     Style["\[FilledCircle]", FontSize -> 16]], 
    Locator[Dynamic[pt2, (pt2 = If[Norm[#] < 1, #, Normalize[#]]) &], 
     Style["\[FilledSquare]", FontSize -> 16]]}, 
   PlotLabel -> Dynamic[Column[{pt1, pt2}]]]]`.

Comment: ...  For arbitrary number of locators see [LocatorPane](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html) and the option [LocatorAutoCreate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorAutoCreate.html) in the docs.

Comment: @kglr, Cool, thank you so much!!! but can I return the complex values to variables? I edited the question in the end. Thank you so much! I look up the doc now.

Comment: @kglr, ha, I think to use something like`ptt1 = Dynamic[pt[[1]]]; ptt2 = Dynamic[pt[[2]]]; Region1S = (ptt1^2 + ptt2^2)/2;` which somehow can changes the color. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Here is kglr's solution rewritten using `LocatorPane`, which I think makes the code a little simpler and perhaps clearer. I have also made some changes.

- the locator is configured to appear a sa  disk
- the plot label shows the position of the disk as a complex number

```
With[
  {pts =
     Append[
       #,
       First[#]]& @ Table[{r {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, phi/(2 Pi)}, 
                          {phi, 0, 2 Pi, .1}, {r, 0, 1, .1}]},
  DynamicModule[{pt = {.5, .5}},
    LocatorPane[
      Dynamic[pt, (pt = If[Norm[#] < 1, #, Normalize[#]]) &], 
      Graphics[
        {Polygon[{{0, 0}, First[#1], First[#2]}, 
           VertexColors -> (Hue /@ {{0, 0, 1}, Last[#1], Last[#2]})]& @@@
         Partition[pts[[All, -1, {1, 2}]], 2, 1]}, 
        PlotLabel -> Dynamic[Style[Complex @@ pt, 16, Black]]], 
      Appearance -> Graphics[{Disk[pt, Scaled[.01]]}]]]]
```

[image: pane]

#### Update

The following code allows the user to add and remove points from the graphics.

```
With[
  {pts =
     Append[
      #, 
      First[#]]& @ Table[{r {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, phi/(2 Pi)}, 
                         {phi, 0, 2 Pi, .1}, {r, 0, 1, .1}]},
  DynamicModule[{constrain, dots = {{.5, .5}}},
    constrain = If[Norm[#] < 1, #, Normalize[#]] &;
    LocatorPane[
      Dynamic[dots, (dots = constrain /@ #) &], 
      Graphics[
        {Polygon[
           {{0, 0}, First[#1], First[#2]}, 
            VertexColors -> 
              (Hue /@ {{0, 0, 1}, Last[#1], Last[#2]})] & @@@
         Partition[pts[[All, -1, {1, 2}]], 2, 1],
         Dynamic[Disk[#, Scaled[.01]] & /@ dots]},
        PlotLabel -> Dynamic[Style[Column[Complex @@@ dots], 16, Black]]],
      LocatorAutoCreate -> True,
      Appearance -> None]]]
```

[image: pane]

#### Note

In V11.3, the Documentation Center's instructions for adding and deleting locators are wrong, at least for Mathematica running on MacOS. The correct way to do it is:

- Add a locator: left click on it while holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>
- Remove a locator:  left click on it while holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>

Comment: @kglr has done all the heavy lifting; I'm just presenting an minor variant for the OP consideration.

Comment: wow, thank you so much!!!! That's amazing! by the way, do you know how to add more spots in the disk? In you code, I try to add as`{pt1 = {.5, .5}, pt2 = {.15, .15}, pt3 = {.1, .15}},` and extend your code but failed.

Comment: @m-goldberg, thank you so much. In the end, i post a small question that changing the Rectangle's color by the spot. Later I use something like`real1 = Dynamic[pt[[1]]]; Im1 = Dynamic[pt[[2]]]; Region1S = (real1^2 + Im1^2)/2;Region1Phi = N[ArcTan[real1, Im1]] `, there I can change the transparancy but the color stay one color-- which means the `Region1Phi` doesn't change. I don't know why. could you have a look the question in the end?