# create interactive local site with backgroud mathematica calculations

Tags: web-access

This may be a bit of a weird question but I cannot figure out if this is possible. I need to write a program at work that can be used interactively. By that I mean, it will have several parameters that will be changed (variables values and imported files for analysis) and it will produce graphs and export data in a given format for plotting elsewhere.

Now, I can write the program and share the nb file but I was thinking that maybe it will be better/easier to maintain (?) a sort of website that I could run locally on my workstation, to which my colleagues could connect and be presented with a series of input boxes for the desired variables and a button to run the calculations. At the end the site will refresh and provide the graphics and export options.

The site itself can be very minimal in appearance, maybe some text explaining what is going on and describing the theory behind calculations.

Is such a thing possible or is there some other simpler method to do this? I have only used mathematica for my needs and I am comfortable with it but I have never done something like this.

Cheers

P.S.: not sure that the chosen tag is the most appropriate one!

Comment: You can set up an HTTP server that interacts with Mathematica like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111803/731). You can also build applications that interact with Wolfram Cloud, like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85920/731). [Here](https://github.com/kubaPod/MVue) is a related project, a tool for making browser based interfaces that interact with Wolfram Cloud.