# ContourPlot code that worked in 9 does not work in Mathematica 10

Tags: plotting

I updated to Mathematica 10 from Mathematica 9. I am trying to create contour plots. I have a saved file with some output that I made using Mathematica 9, with the following equation

```
ContourPlot[ Evaluate @ {Table[Re @ Sin[x + I y] == 1/2 k, {k, -25, 25}], 
                     Table[Im @ Sin[x + I y] == 1/2 k, {k, -25, 25}]}, 
         {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

and it worked for me then. This code also worked for Artes, in his answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7292/731).

Now under Mathematica 10 I get a blank graph. I've tried playing around with the equation but am unable to reproduce anything. Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) your tables:

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Flatten@{Table[Re@Sin[x + I y] == 1/2 k, {k, -25, 25}], 
    Table[Im@Sin[x + I y] == 1/2 k, {k, -25, 25}]},
 {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
 PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not know why there has been a change.

Comment: Wow, that's very pretty :)