# Fractal basins of attraction in a Magnetic Pendulum

Tags: graphics, differential-equations, performance-tuning, physics, fractals

I am trying to write a *Mathematica* program that realizes a graphical approximation of the basins of attraction in a [Magnetic pendulum](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~dyong/math164/2006/win/finalreport.pdf) subject to friction and gravity, in which the three magnets are disposed on the vertices of an equilateral triangle. This system is chaotic and has very interesting properties. The basins of attraction look something like this:

[image]

A code I wrote can produce a $400 \times 400$ image such as this (*Caution: no fancy ColorFunctions involved*) in about two hours. The computation seems to be extremely slow.

[image]

Is there any way of having a better rendering, say, full HD 1920x1080 resolution, for the basins of attraction of a magnetic pendulum as the one mentioned that can be run in a farely quick time on a common machine?

### Code

Here is the code I used to produce the above image. I set the position of the magnets and define the Lagrange equations

```
X1 = 1; X2 = -(1/2); X3 = -(1/2); Y1 = 0; Y2 = Sqrt[3]/2; Y3 = -(Sqrt[3]/2); 
X[1] = X1; X[2] = X2; X[3] = X3; Y[1] = Y1; Y[2] = Y2; Y[3] = Y3;
Eqs[k_,c_,h_]:={
                 x''[t]+k x'[t]+c x[t]-Sum[(X[i]-x[t])/(h^2+(X[i]-x[t])^2+(Y[i]-y[t])^2)^(3/2),{i,3}]==0,
                 y''[t]+k y'[t]+c y[t]-Sum[(Y[i]-y[t])/(h^2+(X[i]-x[t])^2+(Y[i]-y[t])^2)^(3/2),{i,3}]==0
                }
```

I define a function that numerically integrates the equations up until $t=100$.

```
Sol[k_, c_, h_, xo_, yo_] :=
                           NDSolve[
                                   Flatten[{Evaluate[Eqs[k, c, h]],
                                   x'[0] == 0, y'[0]== 0, x[0] == xo, y[0] == yo}],
                                   {x, y}, {t, 99.5, 100.5}, Method -> "Adams"
                                  ];
```

I define a function tt that gives a value between $\frac13, \frac 23, 1$ based on magnet proximity at time $100$ for fixed $k,c,h$ (in this case $.15$,$.2$,$.2$) and a function k that evaluates tt on a grid.

```
tt = Compile[{{x1, _Real}, {y1, _Real}}, Module[{},
            Final = ({x[100], y[100]} /. (Sol[0.15, .2, .2, x1, y1])[[1]]);
            Distances = Map[(Final - #).(Final - #) &, {{1, 0}, {-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}}];
            Magnet = Min[Distances];
            Position[Distances, Magnet][[1, 1]]/3]];
k[n_, xm_, ym_, xM_, yM_] := ParallelTable[tt[xi, yi], {yi, ym, yM, Abs[yM - ym]/n}, {xi, xm, xM, Abs[xM - xm]/n}];
```

Finally, I rasterize the table produced by k.

```
G = Graphics[Raster[k[400, -2, -2, 2, 2], ColorFunction -> Hue]]
```

and, after a while, I obtain the previous image. I attempted using a dynamic energy control (i.e. using EvaluationMonitor to monitor the energy level of ther trajectory: if it falls in a potential hole NDSolve throws the position) but this did not increase the speed as much as I was hoping; it actually seems to slow the computation down.

Comment: Why don't you start by sharing the code you wrote? Perhaps we can improve on that, rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You might want to look up previous work by Paul Nylander.

Comment: @MarcoB Sure, I'll edit the post. My code just sounded like "The obvious thing to do" and did not seem worth sharing. I'll post it in the next few minutes!

Comment: There is a syntax error (`Y3 = -(Sqrt3]/2);`) in the first code block. When I run `Sol[0.15, .2, .2, 1, 1]` I get an error message saying that the system is undetermined, because of lack of spaces between `c` and `x` and `y`.

Comment: @C.E. Thanks, I edited with the correct version. In my code, the constants were $\eta, \gamma, h$, I changed them for better readability and made some mistakes while copying the code. Now it should work.

Comment: After modernizing Nylander's code for the current version, I managed [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ8Rd.png).

Comment: @J.M. This seems very interesting. Can you share your code with us? How much time did the computation take?

Comment: Before that: did you look up Nylander's code like I said in my first comment?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I have found [this](http://bugman123.com/Fractals/index.html#MagneticPendulum).

Comment: If you want to try things out, use Nylander's second snippet, which is using a Beeman integrator. This looks to be faster than native `NDSolve[]` for this specific case.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

JM commented:

> If you want to try things out, use Nylander's second snippet, which is
>   using a Beeman integrator. This looks to be faster than native
>   NDSolve[] for this specific case.

Paul Nylander's code is [here](http://bugman123.com/Fractals/index.html#MagneticPendulum).

Below is a modified version of his code which computes all points simultaneously using the fact that all the operations in Beeman's algorithm are `Listable` functions in Mathematica.

The run time for the 400x400 image is around 30 seconds.

```
n = 400; 
{tmax, dt} = {25, 0.05};
{k, c, h} = {0.15, 0.2, 0.2};
{z1, z2, z3} = N@Exp[I 2 Pi {1, 2, 3}/3];
l = 2.0;

z = Developer`ToPackedArray @ Table[x + I y, {y, -l, l, 2 l/n}, {x, -l, l, 2 l/n}];
v = a = aold = 0 z;
Do[
  z += v dt + (4 a - aold) dt^2/6;
  vpredict = v + (3 a - aold) dt/2; 
  anew = (z1 - z)/(h^2 + Abs[z1 - z]^2)^1.5 + (z2 - z)/(h^2 + Abs[z2 - z]^2)^1.5 +
    (z3 - z)/(h^2 + Abs[z3 - z]^2)^1.5 - c z - k vpredict; 
  v += (5 anew + 8 a - aold) dt/12;
  aold = a; a = anew,
  {t, 0, tmax, dt}];
res = Abs[{z - z1, z - z2, z - z3}];
Image[0.2/res, Interleaving -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: `complexGrid` from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7359) might be useful.

Comment: Turn the `Do` into `Table` and return `z` each time to see a trippy animation: https://cl.ly/3C163h1A3F26

Comment: @Chip, I believe Nylander did something like that in one of the animations on his website.

Comment: @J.M. Ah-ha! I should've clicked the link!

Answer (score 16):

I don't have any breakthrough ideas, but I am able to cut the computation time in half on my computer by optimizing the usage of `NDSolve`.

My version of your code looks like this:

```
X[1] = 1;
X[2] = -(1/2);
X[3] = -(1/2);
Y[1] = 0;
Y[2] = Sqrt[3]/2;
Y[3] = -Sqrt[3]/2;

Sol[k_, c_, h_, xo_, yo_] := NDSolve[{
    x''[t] + k x'[t] + c x[t] - Sum[(X[i] - x[t])/(h^2 + (X[i] - x[t])^2 + (Y[i] - y[t])^2)^(3/2), {i, 3}] == 0, 
    y''[t] + k y'[t] + c y[t] - Sum[(Y[i] - y[t])/(h^2 + (X[i] - x[t])^2 + (Y[i] - y[t])^2)^(3/2), {i, 3}] == 0,
    x'[0] == 0,
    y'[0] == 0,
    x[0] == xo,
    y[0] == yo
    }, {x, y}, {t, 99.5, 100.5}, Method -> "Adams"
   ];

nf = Nearest[{{1, 0}, {-0.5, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-0.5, -Sqrt[3]/2}} -> Automatic] /* First;
getBasin[x1_, y1_] := nf[{x[100], y[100]} /. Sol[0.15, .2, .2, x1, y1] // Flatten, 1]
```

You are essentially building your own `Nearest` function, but one is already built in. This approach is as performant as your code.

Some advanced usage tips for `NDSolve` are documented [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html). The idea is that before `NDSolve` can start to integrate the equations it needs to rewrite them, and this takes time. Instead of doing the rewriting for every single point we can do it just once and then use that for all of the points.

```
getStateData[k_, c_, h_, x0_, y0_] := 
 First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{
    x''[t] + k x'[t] + c x[t] - Sum[(X[i] - x[t])/(h^2 + (X[i] - x[t])^2 + (Y[i] - y[t])^2)^(3/2), {i, 3}] == 0, 
    y''[t] + k y'[t] + c y[t] - Sum[(Y[i] - y[t])/(h^2 + (X[i] - x[t])^2 + (Y[i] - y[t])^2)^(3/2), {i, 3}] == 0,
    x'[0] == 0,
    y'[0] == 0,
    x[0] == x0,
    y[0] == y0
    }, {x, y}, t, Method -> "Adams"]

sd = getStateData[.15, .2, .2, 1, 1];

getBasin2[x0_, y0_] := Module[{state = sd, sol},
  state = First@NDSolve`Reinitialize[state, {x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}];
  NDSolve`Iterate[state, 100.5];
  sol = {x[100], y[100]} /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state];
  nf[sol]
  ]
```

Let's test it:

```
ArrayPlot[
  ParallelTable[getBasin2[xpos, ypos], {xpos, -2, 2, 0.1}, {ypos, -2, 2, 0.1}],
  ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Green, 3 -> Blue}
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This simple example took 22 seconds for me to generate, as opposed to 44.5 seconds for my first rewritten version of your code.

Your image I was able to generate in 33 minutes rather than the two hours it took for you:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Implementing a stopping condition seems cumbersome, but you can also achieve speed enhancements by lowering the amount of integration time. Integrating to 100 seems excessive, with 25 it looks the same for the 400x400 case and it takes only 11 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

I read Paul Nylander's code too and I based my code on Simon Woods and JM's work. The plot part was tough to understand for me as a beginner. Besides, I wanted to change the number of magnets, color,... I thought the modifications would interest some people. Here is my code:

```
SetAttributes[ShowProgress, HoldAll];
ShowProgress[a_, {i_, min_, max_}] := 
 With[{progressStartTime = AbsoluteTime[]}, 
  Monitor[a, 
   Dynamic[Refresh[
     Row[{ProgressIndicator[
         Dynamic[i], {min, max}], {(i/(max - min)*100) // N, "% ", 
         AbsoluteTime[] - progressStartTime, "secondes"}} // Flatten, 
      " "], UpdateInterval -> 0.25]]]]
n = 400;
nbmagnet = 3;
{tmax, dt} = {25, 0.05};
{k, c, h} = {0.15, 0.2, 0.2};
posmagnet = Table[N[Exp[I 2 Pi i/nbmagnet]], {i, 1, nbmagnet}];
l = 5.0;
progression = 0;
z = Developer`ToPackedArray@
   Table[x + I y, {y, -l, l, 2 l/n}, {x, -l, l, 2 l/n}];
v = a = aold = 0 z;
ShowProgress[Do[z = z + v dt + ( 4 a - aold) dt^2/6;
   vpredict = v + (3 a - aold) dt/2;
   anew = 
    Sum[(posmagnet[[i]] - 
         z)/(h*h + Abs[posmagnet[[i]] - z]^2)^1.5, {i, 1, nbmagnet}] -
      c z - k vpredict;
   progression = progression + dt;
   v = v + (5 anew + 8 a - aold) dt/12;
   aold = a; a = anew;, {t, 0, tmax, dt}]; , {progression, 0, 
  tmax + dt}]
res = Table[Abs[z - posmagnet[[i]]], {i, 1, nbmagnet}];
res = Transpose[res, {3, 2, 1}];
r = Table[
   Extract[Extract[Position[res[[i, j]], Min[res[[i, j]]]], 1], 
    1], {i, 1, n + 1}, {j, 1, n + 1}];
ArrayPlot[r, 
 ColorRules -> {1 -> Black, 2 -> White, 3 -> Red, 4 -> Green, 
   5 -> Yellow, 6 -> Black}]
```

And here is an example with 4 magnets. The run time for 1000x1000 image is around 2 minutes

[image: 4 magnets example]

Answer (score 1):

Paul Nylander's first code [(here)](http://bugman123.com/Fractals/index.html#MagneticPendulum) is listed here:

```
 (* runtime: 25 seconds, increase n for higher resolution *)
 n = 40; h = 0.25; g = 0.2; mu = 0.07;
 zlist = {Sqrt[3] + I, -Sqrt[3] + I, -2I};
 image = Table[z2 = z[25] /. NDSolve[{z''[t] == Plus @@ ((zlist - z[t])/(h^2 + Abs[zlist - z[t]]^2)^1.5) - g z[t] - mu z'[t], z[0] == x + I y, z'[0] == 0}, z, {t, 0, 25}, MaxSteps -> 200000][[1]]; r = Abs[z2 - zlist]; i = Position[r, Min[r]][[1, 1]]; Hue[i/3], {y, -5.0, 5.0, 10.0/n}, {x, -5.0,5.0, 10.0/n}];
 Show[Graphics[RasterArray[image]], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

He claims that it works in Mathematica 5.  It does not work in Mathematica 12. (don't know how to correct that). `NDSolve` gives error message regarding boolean expression instead seeing the expected equation.  I believe it is `z''[t]== Plus @@` that makes `NDSolve` confused. I myself do not understand this expression.  The reason this algorithm works a bit faster is that because instead of two equations in solver, you have one equation to solve.  The author mix two variables x,y as one variable z that has real part x and imaginary part y. Although it is more difficult to read and understand not to mention easier to make mistake.  Furthermore `RasterArray` is obsolete.  Use `Raster`.

Comment: "He claims that it works in Mathematica 5. It does not work in Mathematica 12." - versions 6 and onward were quite the big change from version 5, so quite a bit of adjustment is necessary when adapting old code.

Comment: In any case, try this updated code: `With[{n = 40, h = 0.25, g = 0.2, mu = 0.07, zlist = {Sqrt[3] + I, -Sqrt[3] + I, -2 I}}, nf = Nearest[zlist -> Automatic]; pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[{z''[t] == Total[(zlist - z[t])/(h^2 + Abs[zlist - z[t]]^2)^(3/2)] - g z[t] - mu z'[t], z[0] == z0, z'[0] == 0}, z[25], {t, 0, 25}, {z0}]; Graphics[Raster[Table[First[nf[pf[x + I y]]]/3, {y, -5, 5, 10/n}, {x, -5, 5, 10/n}], ColorFunction -> Hue]]]`. Crank up `n` as seen fit.

Comment: @ J.M.'s technical difficulties:  Your code works.   It took 16s on my computer.  A great improvement.

Comment: I must admit that I have a hard time understanding the method of displaying results.  The code that is closest to my understanding of data is C.E. first code.  I understand physics of magnetic pendulum and its equations.  From there, NDSolve is used to calculate a path of bob.  NDSolve is used couple times to create many paths from the same initial position?  How the code chooses color for each path with regards to magnets and plots it? nf? Is there a site explaining this?

Comment: In your code, the definition of z0 is missing, see ( z[0]==z0)

Comment: Did you perhaps notice that `z0` is the *last* argument in `ParametricNDSolveValue[]`?

Comment: It means that it is unknown and needs to be solved.