# IRR Plot on Complex Plane

Tags: plotting, graphics, finance

How do I plot the solutions of

```
Sum[cf1[[i, 2]] E^(-r cf1[[i, 1]]), {i, Length@cf1}] == 0
```

where

```
cf1 = {{0, -100}, {1, 10}, {2, 10}, {3, 110}}
```

as lines on the complex plane?
The equation is an simple example of an internal rate of return problem.
To restate, I know that `FindRoot` will give me the answer in reals. I want to demonstrate that, on the complex plane, the answer is much more, ahh..., complex.

Comment: What is `r` supposed to be?

Comment: r is the interest rate, the internal rate of return that makes the present value of these cashflows equal to zero under continuous compounding.

Comment: ...and certainly those are supposed to be real; however, you want to know about complex solutions fo the resulting equation, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My try.

```
cf1 = {{0, -100}, {1, 10}, {2, 10}, {3, 110}};
f[r_] := Sum[cf1[[i, 2]]/E^(r*cf1[[i, 1]]), {i, Length[cf1]}]

sol[A_] := Chop@Normal[r /. NSolve[f[r] == 0, r]] /. C[1] -> A
(* A is Integer according to the ConditionalExpression that I get rid of with Normal *)

pts = Flatten[#, 1] &@Table[sol[a], {a, 0, 15}];

ListPlot[ReIm /@ pts, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}]
```

[image]

Those are only the complex solutions to the equation `f[r] == 0`.

---

If you want something "prettier", use the [`domainPlot` function written by Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7359/22013):

```
domainPlot[f, 3]
```

[image]

```
domainPlot[f, 1]
```

[image]

Comment: that is gorgeous, better than what I had in mind.

Comment: Remember to upvote the excellent answer of Simon Woods that I linked in my post, after you gain enough reputation to do so.

Comment: How do I show that as a Plot3D?

Comment: Got it, Plot3D[ReIm@f[Complex[a, b]], {a, -3, 3}, {b, -3, 3}]

Comment: But when I look closely, the resulting surface is actually two surfaces. What is happening?

Comment: @Nicholas, that's because your command plotted the real part and imaginary part as two separate surfaces. Use `Re[]` or `Im[]` if you only want one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

```
cf1 = {{0, -100}, {1, 10}, {2, 10}, {3, 110}};

f[r_] = Sum[cf1[[i, 2]] E^(-r cf1[[i, 1]]), {i, Length@cf1}] // Simplify;
```

[**`Solve`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) will provide exact solutions

```
sol[m_] = Solve[f[r] == 0, r] /. C[1] -> m // Normal // Simplify

(*  {{r -> 2/3 I (-1 + 3 m) π}, 
     {r -> 2/3 I (π + 3 m π)}, 
     {r -> 2 I m π + Log[11/10]}}
```

The solutions are three points in the complex plane for each integer `m`

Verifying the solutions

```
And @@ (f[r] == 0 /. sol[m] //
   FullSimplify[#, Element[m, Integers]] &)

(*  True  *)
```

Note that [**`ReIm`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html) is [**`Listable`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html)

```
Attributes[ReIm]

(*  {Listable, Protected}  *)

pts = ReIm[Table[r /. sol[m], {m, -2, 2}]];

ListPlot[Tooltip[pts],
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"Re[r]", "Im[r]"}),
 PlotLegends -> Range[-2, 2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I took the answers from Solve and did the following:

```
t1 = Table[ReIm[-((2 I \[Pi])/3) + 2 I \[Pi] n], {n, -5, 10}];
t2 = Table[ReIm[(2 I \[Pi])/3 + 2 I \[Pi] n], {n, -5, 10}];
t3 = Table[ReIm[2 I \[Pi] n + Log[11/10]], {n, -5, 10}];
Show@Graphics[{Point[t1], Point[t2], Point[t3]},
  Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

It works but I was hoping for something prettier.

Comment: Try `ListPlot[t1~Join~t2~Join~t3]`. But what did you hope for?