# Visualizing the Riemann zeta function

Tags: special-functions, complex, visualization

How to visualize in a nice geometric way (e.g., like in [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD0NjbwqlYw)) the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta (z)$?

Comment: FWIW, here's a barebones version of one of the pictures shown in that video: `ParametricPlot[ReIm[Zeta[r Exp[I t]]], {r, 0, 4}, {t, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> True, PlotStyle -> None]`. You might also be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7275).

Comment: @J.M. Nice `ParametricPlot`. Why not post an answer?

Comment: It's "barebones", as I said. Somebody else might want to make something more stylish out of it. :) If you're looking for other visualization ideas, you might be able to adapt the ones used at the [Wolfram Functions site](http://functions.wolfram.com/visualizations.html).

Comment: Plot the real function $\xi(1/2+it), t \in \mathbb{R}$ where $\xi(s) = s(s-1)\pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2) \zeta(s)$, then do the same with the Hurwitz zeta functions, and see how the RH fails for those

Comment: @user1952009, and `RiemannXi[]` is built-in, too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the visualisations in the linked video is similar to the following. Parameter `t` is the imaginary value (height) above the real axis.

```
Manipulate[
   Module[{p, c, z},
      p = Table[RiemannSiegelZ[t]*{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, tmax - dt, dt}];
      c = Table[ColorData["DarkRainbow", t/tmax], {t, 0, tmax - dt, dt}];
      z = Im[N[ZetaZero[Range[tmax]]]];
      Graphics[{
         Red, Line[{{-4, 0}, {4, 0}}], Line[{{0, -4}, {0, 4}}],
         Thick, Line[Take[p,Floor[t/dt]], VertexColors->Take[c,Floor[t/dt]]]},
         PlotLabel -> ToString[Select[z, # <= t &]], Background -> Black,
         PlotRange -> 4 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12},
         ImageSize -> 600]
      ],
{{tmax, 60., "Maximum t"}, 3, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{dt, 0.1, "Delta t"}, 0.03, 0.3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{t, 0.0, "Parameter t"}, 0.0, tmax, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: zeta manipulation]

Or try an animation:

```
Module[{tmax = 60, dt = 0.1, p, c, z},
   p = Table[RiemannSiegelZ[t]*{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, tmax - dt, dt}];
   c = Table[ColorData["DarkRainbow", t/tmax], {t, 0, tmax - dt, dt}];
   z = Im[N[ZetaZero[Range[tmax]]]];
   Animate[
      Graphics[{
      Red, Line[{{-4, 0}, {4, 0}}], Line[{{0, -4}, {0, 4}}],
      Thick, Line[Take[p, Floor[t/dt]], VertexColors->Take[c,Floor[t/dt]]]},
      PlotLabel -> ToString[Select[z, # <= t &]], Background -> Black,
      PlotRange -> 4 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12},
      ImageSize -> 500],
  {t, 0.0, tmax}, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
]
```

The curving coloured line plots the complex value of `w=Zeta[1/2+ I t]` as real `t` increases from zero. The red axes are the real part of `w` (horizontal) and imaginary part of `w` (vertical). As each non-trivial zeta-function root is encountered on this critical line `x=1/2`, the curve passes through the origin and the plot label appends its `t` value to a list.

Comment: I'd add that this way of visualizing $\zeta$ is especially interesting for demonstrating [Lehmer's phenomenon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LehmersPhenomenon.html).

Answer (score 8):

One way is to show the convergence of the defining sum.

### Background

The zeta function is defined as

$$\zeta (s)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^s}=\frac{1}{1^s}+\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}+\ldots$$

which is:

- divergent for $s=1$;
- gives *nice* values for other positive integers, e.g. `Zeta[2]`$=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$;
- is well defined on the complex plane **if** $\Re (s)>1$;
- when  $\Re (s)\leq 1$, the sum is *divergent*, e.g. $\zeta (-1)=1+2+3+4+\ldots$. However, one can perform a unique analytic continuation that ascribes a value of $-\frac{1}{12}$ to $\zeta (-1)$ (not to be covered here).

For $s\in\mathbb{C}$, e.g. $s=2+i$, the sum will be

$$\frac{1}{1^2 1^i}+\frac{1}{2^2 2^i}+\frac{1}{3^2 3^i}+\frac{1}{4^2 4^i}+\ldots$$

Each of the terms consists of a purely real and a purely imaginary exponent (referred to as *part* in short). The real part describes the *length* of the number (i.e., $\frac{1}{1^2}=1$ says the number is 1 unit from $(0,0)$; $\frac{1}{2^2}=1/4$ says that the number is $1/4$ units from the *previous* number, etc.); the imaginary part describes an angle. Given this, each term describes a vector starting from the end of the previous one.

### Code

Defining a partial sum of $n$ terms:

```
zeta[s_, n_] := Table[1/k^s, {k, 1, n}]
```

one can visualize the addition of partial vectors in the complex plane with

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{loc = {2., 1.}}, 
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[loc], 
   Dynamic@ListLinePlot[
     Accumulate@
      Partition[
       Join[{{0, 0}}, ReIm /@ zeta[loc[[1]] + loc[[2]] I, n]], 2, 1], 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-2, 2}}, Frame -> True, 
     AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotLabel -> If[loc[[1]] <= 1, "Divergent", "Convergent"], 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], 
       Point@ReIm@Zeta[loc[[1]] + loc[[2]] I]}]
   ]
  ]
 , {n, {100, 500, 1000}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

The Locator shows the input value $s$; the red point shows the exact value `Zeta[s]`; the spiral with colorful segments shows the partial vectors in the complex plane. `n` can be varied. One can see that when $\Re (s)$ is close to $1$, the convergence is very slow.

Comment: You could use `Accumulate[Partition[ReIm[Prepend[1/Range[n]^({1, I}.loc), 0]], 2, 1]]` instead for the expression within `ListLinePlot[]`.

Comment: $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx)$ for $Re(s) > 0$ is more interesting, and the convergence is slow when $t$ gets large (see the Lindelöf hypothesis)

Answer (score 6):

```
rz[u_, v_] := With[{i = Complex[u, v]}, ReIm[Zeta[i]]]
szf[{u_, v_}, n_Integer] := {{0, 0}}~Join~
  N@Table[ReIm[Sum[1/j^(u + I v), {j, 1, k}]], {k, 1, n}]
Manipulate[
 Row[{ParametricPlot[{u, v}, {u, -r, r}, {v, -r, r}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &}, Mesh -> {10, 10}, 
    Exclusions -> None, ImageSize -> 400, 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[p]}],
   ParametricPlot[rz[u, v], {u, -r, r}, {v, -r, r}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &}, Mesh -> {10, 10}, 
    Exclusions -> None, ImageSize -> 400, 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[rz @@ p], Green, 
      Line[szf[p, number]], Black, Point[szf[p, number]]
      }, PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}}]}], {{p, {1, 
    1}}, {-r, -r}, {r, r}, 
  Slider2D}, {{r, 2}, {2, 5, 10, 20}}, {number, Range[2, 100]}]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

If you want to see behaviour along Re[z]=1/2:

```
tab1 = Table[{1/2, j}, {j, -30, 30, 0.1}];
tab2 = Table[ReIm[Zeta[1/2 + j I]], {j, -30, 30, 0.1}];
lp1 = ListPlot[tab1, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Dashed, 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[#]}, Frame -> True, 
     ImageSize -> 400] & /@ tab1;
lp2 = ListPlot[tab2, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Dashed, 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[#]}, Frame -> True, 
     ImageSize -> 400] & /@ tab2;
an = Row /@ Thread[{lp1, lp2}];
```

Animated gif is [here](https://ubpdqnmathematica.files.wordpress.com/2016/12/riemann.gif?w=1650&h=)

Answer (score 2):

I improved Corey's answer by animating the partial sum graph.

I feel this gives good insight into what the zeta function is computing as Im(s) increases.

I added an adjustment for Re(s), to show how zeros only happen along Re(s) = ½.

```
zeta[s_, n_] := Table[1/k^s, {k, 1, n}]

Animate[
 Manipulate[
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[{re, im}],
   Dynamic@ListLinePlot[
     Accumulate@Partition[
       Join[{{0, 0}}, ReIm /@ zeta[re + im I, n]], 2, 1],
     PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1,
      Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[Large], Point@ReIm@Zeta[re + im I]}]],
  {{re, 0.5, "Re(s)"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{n, 50, "Iterations"}, 10, 200, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
 {{im, 0, "Im(s)"}, 0, 1000, AnimationRate -> 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I am fascinated by the asymmetric-symmetry.

[image: Zeta Partial Sum]