# How can I visualize the geometry of the complex mapping $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}$?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to visualize the geometry of the complex mapping $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ using the following codes.

```
g[x_, y_] := {x/(x^2 + y^2), -y/(x^2 + y^2)};

Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]},
   {c, 10 t},
   g[c, t]},
   {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}],
   {c, -3, 3}]
```

What I want to demonstrate is that the image of a straight line under the mapping $g$ is a circle. (And I use `Manipulate` to demonstrate the image for different vertical lines.) But I only get part of the circle since the straight line is actually only a segment in the plot.

[image]

Could anyone help to fix this?

Comment: A somehow [related topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133340/visualizing-the-riemann-zeta-function).

Comment: I didn't mean for you to delete your question, but I couldn't spend the time to write a full answer. Hope you figured it out based on my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not perfect but better:

```
g[x_, y_] := {x/(x^2 + y^2), -y/(x^2 + y^2)};

Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {c, 10 t}}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}],
  ParametricPlot[g[c, t], {t, -100, 100}]],
 {c, -3, 3}]
```

*Trick:* You can improve the smoothness of the parametric circle during manipulate by replacing the second plot as follows:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {c, 10 t}}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}],
  ParametricPlot[g[c, t^5], {t, -2, 2}] ],
 {{c, -1.5}, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Add PlotPoints -> 1000 in ParametricPlot for full of happiness.

Comment: @user64494 this may be machine-dependent it does not help on my 2015 Macbook Pro. However the above added *trick* did.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the `-1.5` for in `{c, -1.5}, -3, 3}`?

Comment: Enlighten by your answer, one can replace `g[c,t]` with `g[c,t^7]` in my original code to get the desired result.

Comment: @Jack -1.5 is the initial value of c.

Comment: @A.G.: I didn't know that before. Nice to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_, y_] := ReIm[1/(x + I y)]
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{{a + b Cos[t], c + b Sin[t]}, 
   f[a + b Cos[t], c + b Sin[t]]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"z", "1/z"}], {{a, 0}, -2, 2}, {{b, 1}, 0.1, 
  2}, {{c, 0}, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have never seen the use of `ReIm` before. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask how you made the gif from Mathematica?

Comment: @Jack  I use [LICECap](https://licecap.en.softonic.com/)