# Issue visualizing the image of a vertical line under 1/z using ComplexContourPlot

Tags: plotting, complex, inverse-function

I am using the function ComplexContourPlot to try to get the image of a vertical line under 1/z however I am getting an error.

In this case I would like to see the image of 1/z for the vertical line that goes from 3-3i to 3+3i

```
ComplexContourPlot[1/z, {z, 3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}]
```

This is the result I am getting:

```
ComplexContourPlot::plld: Corners for z in {z,3-3 I,3+3 I} must have distinct machine-precision real and imaginary parts.
```

I have managed to show correctly the circle using a ParametricPlot and working directly with the components u and v.

```
ParametricPlot[{{3/(3^2 + y^2), -( y/(3^2 + y^2))}}, {y, -20, 20}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

But I want to work directly with Z not divide into the separate real and imaginary parts, how can I do this using Mathematica 12?.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by *vertical line under $1/z$?* This is a vertical line: ``ComplexContourPlot[Re[z] == 1, {z, 3}]`` And for the circle: ``ComplexContourPlot[Abs[z - 1] == 2, {z, 3}]`` If you want to visualize mappings, look at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137638/how-can-i-visualize-the-geometry-of-the-complex-mapping-gz-frac1z?rq=1)

Comment: I noticed an error in my original question there was a mistake in how I entered the parameters into ComplexContourPlot. Yes I saw the question, but in that one, is separating real and imaginary parts. I would like to know how to do it directly with z.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the level set of `Re[1/z]`? Maybe the `curve1` is what you want to draw.

```
curve1 = ComplexContourPlot[Re[1/z] == 3, {z, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}, 
  PlotPoints -> 80, ContourStyle -> Red]
curve2 = ParametricPlot[{{3/(3^2 + y^2), -(y/(3^2 + y^2))}}, {y, -20, 
   20}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
Show[curve1, curve2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ComplexContourPlot` draws contour lines of a real function of complex arguments. However, 1/z is not a real function of complex arguments..

To draw the complex values of 1/z over the line 3-3 I to 3+3I you may use `AbsArgPlot` This will draw the absolute value and color the line according to the argument:

AbsArgPlot[1/(3 + I y), {y, -3, 3}]

[image]

Comment: I thought that in Mathematica every number is a complex number, so I thought by default z would be taken as complex, in ComplexContourPlot.