# Plot an array of complex numbers

Tags: plotting, visualization

In version `12.0` Mathematica introduced a new function `ComplexPlot`. So how can I plot an array of complex numbers, with `ArrayPlot`, that colors the numbers in a similar way to `ComplexPlot`?
The post [How can I generate this "domain coloring" plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7275/how-can-i-generate-this-domain-coloring-plot) is helpful but did not directly address my problem, as what I was looking for was rather a plot of an array, with the exact coloring rules as `ComplexPlot`

Comment: Have you read this post?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7275/1871

Comment: @xzczd Thanks! That post was hard to find from my keywords

Comment: Something like `ColorFunction -> Hue` seems to be to the right direction when used in `ArrayPlot`. You can check against the colors of `domainPlot[]` from the link that @xzczd provided

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0D But then how can I change the brightness of the colors?