# Specifying Contours in "CyclicReImLogAbs" for ComplexPlot/ComplexPlot3D

Tags: plotting, color, complex

How can I specify where and/or how many contours appear in ComplexPlot and ComplexPlot3D when using the "CyclicReImLogAbs" color function? I'm referring specifically to the black and white lines in such plots (see below).

A minimal example:

`ComplexPlot3D[z^2, {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}, ColorFunction -> "CyclicReImLogAbs"]`

[image]

Comment: The documentation seems to indicate that the dark and light highlighted lines that you refer to are characteristics of the function being plotted, ergo, to change the number and location of such lines, you should change the function itself.

Comment: This doesn’t make sense to me. As far as I can tell, the black lines are contours of constant Re(f), Im(f), and the white lines are contours of constant Abs[Log[f]]. Certainly different functions will have different contour, yes... but I am asking how to specify *which* contours appear for a given function, eg as in ContourPlot.

Comment: Unfortunately, the spacing of the contours is baked into the color function. You would need to use something like Simon's code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7359), if you need that level of customization. On the other hand, you could [request this feature to Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/).

Comment: What is “Simon’s code”?